# Redefine \texttt{} to allow underscore

Tags: typewriter, renewcommand

I use underscore inside `\texttt{}` quite often to represent python functions, and I get quite tired of escaping every single underscore with `\_`. I tried the following to redefine the `\texttt{}` command to allow unescaped underscores, based on these answers:

[Can I redefine a command to contain itself?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/232188/10261)

[To escape underscore without \verb and \texttt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47353/102613)

For some reason, it doesn't work. If I write the three lines inside the command directly in my text, it works. Any ideas to why this doesn't work?

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\let\oldtexttt\texttt #'Copy' command

\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{
\catcode`_ 12\relax    
\oldtexttt{#1}
\catcode`_ 8\relax}

\texttt{hello_world}
```

Comment: Can't you just use the next answer there? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38721/250119 // By the way, I don't recommend trying to change catcode when you don't truly understand the things, as it can go horribly wrong later and it will be hard to debug. Learn them properly if you want (TeXbook or TeX by Topic)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should define your own command for Python functions, to which apply a character substitution.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\pyf}{m}
 {
  \texttt
   {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
    \tl_replace_all:Nen \l_tmpa_tl { \char_generate:nn { `_ } { 8 } } { \_ }
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn { Ne }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\pyf{my_var}

\texttt{my\_var}

\end{document}
```

There is a little complication due to the fact that `_` is special in the `expl3` programming environment, so we need to generate the underscore with its usual meaning of “subscript”.

[image]

Your approach cannot work because when you absorb the argument the category codes are frozen. You might do it by *not* absorbing the argument before the category code change

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pyf}{%
  \begingroup\catcode`_=12
  \pyf@
}
\newcommand{\pyf@}[1]{\texttt{#1}\endgroup}
\makeatother
```

but this will *not* work if you use `\pyf` in the argument to another command.

The code I showed at the beginning is free from this defect.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't suppose this would work if I want to redefine \texttt?

Comment: @EsbenF. You might redefine `\texttt`, but why? You have a special construction, so give it a special name.