# Error message: "I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol..."

Tags: math-mode

In laTeX I have this line:

```
<onEntry>do_something </onEntry>
```

which is giving me this error:

```
$
l.28 <onEntry>do_
something </onEntry>
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
! Missing $ inserted.
```

I just want to write the line as it is... not special nothing.

And I have no idea how to solve this. I already search for this issue but all I found was real issues related to use of math symbol and not something like this... where there is no math at all.

Can you help me ?

Comment: You can't use an underscore directly in text mode, it signifies a math subscript.  Try `\_`

Comment: The underscore is a math-mode character. If you use it in the macro names you will get an error.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48632/15925

Comment: Also, check out \verb