# How to italicise a number in a math environment?

Tags: math-mode, formatting, italic

When typing 'variable0' in a math mode, only the letters are italicised. How can I force the 0 to be italicised as well?

Comment: words shouldn't be treated as "ordinary" math.  the whole thing should be treated as a unit; if all italic, then `$ \mathit{variable0} $`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually numbers are not italicized, but it is possible, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[\mathit{01234567890}\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to define a macro that handles the formatting of your "variable names", so you can have some consistent output in your document, regardless of where you use it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139980/5764
\newcommand{\var}[1]{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\[
  \var{variable}_0 \quad
  \var{AbC}_{13} \quad
  \var{some_thing}_i
\]
\end{document}
```

I've used `\texttt`, but you can use whatever text formatting you want to highlight a text-related variable.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question.

Comment: @RandyCragun: Correct. I was more trying to suggest that one should define macros for consistency that you can change as needed. For example, if you're working with *variables* within you math environment(s), define a macro that formats these variables (say, `\var`). Then you can change it to use `\mathit` or `\texttt`, depending on what you want it to be formatted as.