# Quote verbatim in Latex

Tags: math-mode, verbatim

I would like to quote some passages using the `quote` environment. However the quoted passage contains some math mode equations written in text format like "Your paper is worthless because x^2 +y^2 = 0." I would like to be able to quote this as is, without using the math-mode. Is there something like a mixture of verbatim and quote environments so that I don't have to go through every instance of such equations and replace them with something like `\verb*x^2+y^2=0*`? Something perhaps with some flexibility in the choice of fonts too.

EDIT: Basically, what I want is all the text-handling capabilities of LaTeX for the quoted text, while treating things like a^2+b^2 = 0 as is, just some characters to be displayed verbatim. I don't know if this is achievable without surrounding a^2+b^2=0 or the like with special characters.

Comment: Please provide MWE!

Comment: how are Greek letters `\sigma`... or symbols `\sum`, `\prod` supposed to be treated ?

Comment: @jfbu, exactly as they are written `\sigma, \sum, \prod`. People often do this when writing emails with math symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set this "verbatim quote" as a regular listing. Below I defined a new listing `verbquote`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,lipsum}

\lstnewenvironment{verbquote}[1][]
  {\lstset{columns=fullflexible,
           basicstyle=\ttfamily,
           xleftmargin=2em,
           xrightmargin=2em,
           breaklines,
           breakindent=0pt,
           #1}}% \begin{verbquote}[..]
  {}% \end{verbquote}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{verbquote}
Your paper is worthless because x^2 + y^2 = 0. Please reconsider what you are attempting.
\lipsum[2]
\end{verbquote}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

All content within `verbquote` will be set as-is. You can change the font (or any other styles) using any of the options provided for [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings).

---

You can also just reset the category codes of active keys that could cause problems to print them as "other" (category code 12):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48632/5764

\newenvironment{verbquote}
  {\catcode `^=12% Math superscript
   \catcode `_=12% Math subscript
   \catcode `$=12% Math deliniation
   \begin{quote}}
  {\end{quote}}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{verbquote}
Your paper is worthless because x^2 + y_2 = 0 or about $0. Please reconsider what you are attempting.
\end{verbquote}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought the OP wants the regular text font for text material inside a `quote`, and verbatim look (i.e., a monospace font) for math material.

Comment: @Mico, The change of fonts would have been nice, but I guess there is a trade-off with the other thing I want, namely, just copy-pasting what someone wrote without going through adding dollar signs. What I meant by the choice of font was that the whole font for the quoted text need not be typewriter. This answer is closest to what I had in mind.

Comment: @passerby51: You can adjust the `basicstyle` to suit your needs, or whichever font you want.

Comment: @Werner, thanks. I have experimented with your `verbqoute`, and one thing I don't like about it is how it handles the usual text. LaTeX text looks much better, in terms of spacing and end of line breaks, etc. Is there any way to have that so of thing with a verbatim environment?

Comment: @passerby51: I've provided an updated version of `verbquote` that might be useful. There are many more options, but I'm not sure what you might include in the quote.

Comment: @Werner, your second solution with category codes does not seem to work  even the quoted text contains backslashes (which is usual with math mode writing.) Can I change the category code of a backslash? Then who would TeX know when to stop the environment?

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve the same effect as in [Mico's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266506/4686) with the help of package `shortvrb`, to transform `$` temporarily as a switch to verbatim.

The `quote` environment is modified via `etoolbox` exactly as in Mico's answer.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{shortvrb}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\MakeShortVerb\$}
\AtEndEnvironment{quote}{\DeleteShortVerb\$}

\begin{document}
\noindent
$a^2 + b^2 = 0$
\begin{quote}
Your paper is worthless because you claim that $a^2 + b^2 = 0$ and that $1 + 1 = 3$.
\end{quote}
$1 + 1 = 3$
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: +1. I didn't know the `shortvrb` package until I read your answer.

Comment: @jfbu, Thanks. As much as I like this answer, this will require me to go through the quoted text and surround math-mode mark-up with $...$. I wanted to avoid this. I should have made this more clear in my question. Although, your solution is still great for what it does.

Answer (score 3):

I'm interpreting your objective as follows: (i) Inside `quote` environments, and only inside `quote` environments, inline math material -- i.e., stuff that starts and ends with a `$` symbol -- should be typeset automatically using a monospaced font rather than in math mode. (ii) All text-mode material inside `quote` environments should be typeset using the regular text font.

If this interpretation is correct, it may be achieved by using LuaLaTeX and setting up a Lua function which (a) is active only inside `quote` environments and (b) replaces inline math mode with verbatim mode.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

%% Lua-side code
\usepackage{luacode,luatexbase}
\begin{luacode}
do_conversion = false 
function inline_math_to_verbatim ( line )
   if do_conversion then
      return (string.gsub(line,"%$(.-)%$","\\verb&%1&"))
   end
end
-- assign this function to the "process_input_buffer" callback
luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer", 
    inline_math_to_verbatim, "inline_math_to_verbatim" )
\end{luacode}

%% TeX-side code
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\luadirect{do_conversion=true}}
\AtEndEnvironment{quote}{\luadirect{do_conversion=false}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
$a^2 + b^2 = 0$
\begin{quote}
Your paper is worthless because you claim that $a^2 + b^2 = 0$ and that $1 + 1 = 3$.
\end{quote}
$1 + 1 = 3$
\end{document}
```

Comment: @passerby51 -- If you don't use `$` symbols to delimit math-mode material, what method do you use?

Comment: just typset them as if they where text, like X_{ij} = 2 as is.

Comment: @passerby51 -- I didn't ask you how the mathy material should be displayed ("as if [it] were text"). Instead, I asked you how TeX should be made aware that some of the material it's dealing with is mathy.

Comment: Ideally it shouldn't be made aware, just like a simple text editor is not aware of them. They are just characters to be displayed.