# write "Mi_dark energy" in a text paragraph

Tags: code, text

I would like to write "Mi_dark energy" in a text paragraph.

How should I do?

I thought maybe but `\(Mi_\text{dark energy}\)` but it doesn't work. What did I miss out? Thanks.

Comment: Do not forget to put mathematical symbols between $$.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  `_` is reserved for coding subscripts in math mode, for example `$x_a$`.  If you want to escape from it,  you might code like: `\_`, so your coding should be: `Mi\_dark energy`.

Comment: Why not Mi$_\text{dark energy}$ ...

Comment: @MattAllegro: Totally unclear what the O.P. requests. It could be verbatim `\verb+Mi_dark energy+` as well

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Hi! true... I only wrote because I couldn't imagine Mi "in italic" ;)

Comment: @MattAllegro: Of course -- I just commented because the O.P. let's guessing wildly around about the case/sense of the request ;-)

Comment: What's not working? `\(...  \)` changes to math mode. Do you have  `amsmath` loaded? Another question remains: is `Mi` one entity? Or a product of two? Is it a variable? An operator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Underscores in words (text)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48632/underscores-in-words-text)

Comment: @marczellm I don't think so: according to the comments the OP wants a subscript.

Answer (score 1):

Math Mode works like [MWijnand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282085/write-mi-dark-energy-in-a-text-paragraph#comment679911_282085) already told you, but it is not an aesthetic solution.

For the underscores, there is already an answered question here [Underscores in words (text)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48633).

These Solutions are way better (even if they do nearly the same), because it is no math you are doing there, it is text, so you can use a textual solution like these.

To summarize it here are the Solutions:

```
\texttt{Mi\_dark energy}

\verb|Mi_dark energy|

\texttt{Mi\char`_dark energy}
```

Comment: Did it work like you wanted to?