# Math non italic preamble

Tags: math-mode

Is there anyway to set math font as non italic ? I thought this was a pretty good solution [Is there a way to make math mode subscripts automatically non-italic?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158872/is-there-a-way-to-make-math-mode-subscripts-automatically-non-italic) until I started using \sum. I wanted the subscript to be non italic as well.

Comment: Any math fonts package with a `frenchmath` or `upright` option has lowercase greek letters and capital letters upright.

Comment: A [similar question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/330120) has been asked recently, and has got three answers.

Comment: Perhaps you should use an upright math font such as [`eulervm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eulervm).