# How do I define a macro that wraps a text and link to involve an underscore?

Tags: macros, hyperref

I'm documenting some C++ code. Each C++ function will have it's own section in my documentation, and I am trying to have each section labelled and each mention of the function linked.

The macros I am currently using are

```tex
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\cppsection}[1]{\section{#1}\label{#1}}
\newcommand{\cppfcn}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{\texttt{#1}}}
```

which works for the most part...

...except for if the C++ function has an underscore. For example, `\cppsection{my_fcn}` doesn't work as it complains about the underscore for the section name, and `\cppsection{my\_fcn}` doesn't work as it complains about the backslash in the label definition.

This issue is likewise for the `\cppfcn` macro.

So my question is: Is there a way to define my macros to parse underscores for both the text *and* the label?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `\detokenize` the output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\cppsection}[1]{\section{\protect\detokenize{#1}}\label{#1}}
\newcommand{\cppfcn}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\cppsection{function} See \cppfcn{procedure}.

\cppsection{procedure} See \cppfcn{fnc_proc}.

\cppsection{fnc_proc} See \cppfcn{function}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You're a legend, your MWE works fine. But once I add a `\tableofcontents` it fails, complaining about the lack of a math environment for the underscore in the `test.toc` file. Any ideas?

Comment: @kapple: You need to `\protect` certain things that go in the ToC. Answer has been updated.

Comment: Works wonders, thanks heaps!

Answer (score 1):

Probably this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359787/is-it-safe-to-set-underscore-to-a-non-active-character)

And try:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\catcode`_=12
\newcommand\Test[1]{%
  \section{#1}%
}
\begin{document}

\Test{test_test}
Text_text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Now try some math: `$A_b$`.  You could instead do something like ``\newcommand\Test{\begingroup\catcode`\_=12 \Testaux}
\newcommand\Testaux{\endgroup\section}``

Answer (score 1):

```
% optional, not necessary:  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%
\usepackage[english]{babel}% or your language
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{hyperref}
. . . 
\cppsection{my_fcn}
```

Subscripts will still work in math mode.