# How to type special characters?

Tags: xetex

I am trying to print a text in my Latex document, but I get lots of errors and I do not know what to do. The text is:

```
answer([Capital, Country]):-is_country(Country),borders(Country, greece),capital_of(Capital, Country).
```

I believe I have to escape some special characters, but I wonder if there is a more appropriate way to do this.

I use Xelatex on a Windows machine.

Comment: Try to put your text in a verbatim environment. The simplest one is `\verb|your text here|`. If you need something more complex have a look at the listings package.

Comment: The main problem seems to be `_`, which you can obtain using `\_`. See [Underscores in words (text)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48632/5764).

Comment: This looks like you are formmating code, not regular text, so you may want to look at packages designed for this, e.g. `listings`. See e.g. [How to format an inline source code](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/19004) and [Syntax Coloring in LaTeX](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/867).