# Make a command accept underscores without having to type a backslash in front of it

Tags: macros, characters

When using for example `\includegraphics{my_picture.png}` there is
no need to escape the underscore in the file name. I am trying to make my own command to display Python code, but Python identifiers frequently have underscores, so I would like to avoid typing the backslash in front of each underscore. Is it possible?

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\definecolor{Light}{gray}{.90}
\sethlcolor{Light}
\newcommand{\pythonCode}[1]{\mbox{\hl{\texttt{#1}}}}
\chardef\_=`_% See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48632/24422
\begin{document}
\section{\pythonCode{\_NumberDict}}
An instance of this class acts like an array of numbers with
generalized (non-integer) indices. A value of zero is assumed
for undefined entries. \pythonCode{\_NumberDict} instances support addition,
and subtraction with other \pythonCode{\_NumberDict} instances, and multiplication
and division by scalars.
\end{document}
```

How can I modify the `\pythonCode` macro so I can type `\pythonCode{_NumberDict}` instead of `\pythonCode{\_NumberDict}`?

Comment: For source code I would suggest `listings` or `minted`. You could also just use LaTeX's standard `\verb`. But all of these verbatim-like commands/environments have drawbacks (they might be hard to use as arguments of other commands).

Comment: Package `underscore` perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such a simple situation, I'd use `\detokenize`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{Light}{gray}{.90}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\pythonCode}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}%
  \colorbox{Light}{\ttfamily\vphantom{Ay}\detokenize{#1}}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\section{\pythonCode{_NumberDict}}

\pythonCode{_NumberDict}
\pythonCode{_NumberDicty}

\end{document}
```

[image]