# Test if current font is a monospace font

Tags: fonts, pdftex, typewriter

I'm trying to define a command that should give different outputs depending on the currently active font, especially depending on if the font is a monospace or serif/sans serif font.

I know there's `\the\font` to get the currently active font, which in LaTeX gives something like `\OT1/cmr/m/n/10` or `\OT1/cmtt/m/n/10`. This can be split to extract the `cmr`/`cmtt` part and test against this string explicitly. However, I'm wondering if there's a more flexible approach that doesn't require hardcoding the font name.

Using pdflatex, is there a way to test whether the current font is *any* monospace font? If not, is there a built-in option to test if the current font is equal to the default monospace font?

Comment: For the default font you can test \f@family against \ttdefault. For a general monotony check if i and m have the same width.

Comment: To do the check that @UlrikeFischer suggests about i and m try: `\noindent iiiiiiiiii.\\mmmmmmmmmm.` inside your `document` environment and check if the width is the same.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to write up an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, both tests can be performed quite easily.

To test for the **default monospace font**, the expansion of the `\f@family` macro can be compared to the expansion of `\ttdefault`. Note that both macros differ in their prefixes (`\long` in this case), which is especially important when `\ifx` is used.

Testing for **any monospace font** can be done by filling two hboxes with a single character each, where either would have a different width in a proportional font, and comparing the boxes' widths afterwards. `.` and `M` seem reasonable choices to me.

The following code demonstrates the idea by defining tests `\ifttdefault` and `\iftt`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\ifttdefault{%
    \edef\@tempa{\f@family}%
    \edef\@tempb{\ttdefault}%
    \ifx\@tempa\@tempb
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
}

\newcommand\iftt{%
    \begingroup
    \setbox0=\hbox{.}%
    \setbox1=\hbox{M}%
    \ifdim\wd0=\wd1
        \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
        \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frenchspacing

Default monospace font: \ifttdefault{yes}{no}\par
\texttt{Default monospace font: \ifttdefault{yes}{no}}\par
{\fontfamily{txtt}\selectfont Default monospace font: \ifttdefault{yes}{no}}\par
\medskip

Any monospace font: \iftt{yes}{no}\par
\texttt{Any monospace font: \iftt{yes}{no}}\par
{\fontfamily{txtt}\selectfont Any monospace font: \iftt{yes}{no}}\par

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you use `\frenchspacing` here? (I know what it does in general, I just don't see what it illustrates here.)

Comment: @LokiRagnarok With the default setting the space after `:` in the monospace fonts is much bigger than with the proportional font, which is what I wanted to get rid of. It's completely unrelated to the question, though, just a personal obsession with details. :-)