# Drawing Realistic Linux Command Shell Windows with tcolorbox

Tags: listings, tcolorbox, minted, code, command-line

I'm trying to make these little imitation command shell window/box/things. The problem is I can't skip lines. The prompt (aka. `$PS1`) appears on every line; there's no room for the command output. Any ideas? Thanks.

PS: I'm using `tcolorbox` to draw the boxes. I usually use `minted` for code formatting (including elsewhere in the same document), but these boxes use `listings`, like the examples in the manual.

---

#### How it is:

**a)**
[image]
<sup>*LaTeX*</sup>
**b)**
[image]
<sup>*LaTeX*</sup>

---

#### How it should be:

[image]
<sup>*Inkscape*</sup>

---

#### Code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,url}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse,minted,listings}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% This is where it's defined %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newtcblisting{ubuntu}{colback=violet!50!black,colupper=white,
colframe=gray!65!black,listing only,listing options={style=tcblatex,language=sh},
title={\textcolor{orange}{\Huge{$\bullet$}}{\textcolor{gray}{\Huge{$\bullet\bullet$}}}},
every listing line={\textcolor{lime}{\small\ttfamily\bfseries
root@ubuntu{\textcolor{white}:}\textcolor{cyan!60}{\url{~}}{\textcolor{white}\#}}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% This is where it's drawn %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{ubuntu}
whoami \\ root
id \\ uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
hostname \\ ubuntu
_
\end{ubuntu}    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can escape inside a listing. I defined a command that brings you in a new line without adding `root@ubuntu:~#`. (I could only run the code after Tiuri's edit.)

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,url}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse,listings}

\begin{document}

\newtcblisting{ubuntu}{colback=violet!50!black,
colupper=white,colframe=gray!65!black,listing only,
listing options={style=tcblatex,language=sh,escapeinside=||,},
title={\textcolor{orange}{\Huge{$\bullet$}}{\textcolor{gray}{\Huge{$\bullet\bullet$}}}},
every listing line={\textcolor{lime}{\small\ttfamily\bfseries root@ubuntu{\textcolor{white}:}\textcolor{cyan!60}{\url{~}}{\textcolor{white}\#} }}}
\newlength{\Lind}
\setbox0\hbox{\small\ttfamily\bfseries root@}
\setlength{\Lind}{\the\dimexpr\wd0+1pt}
\newcommand{\LR}{\\\hspace*{-\Lind}}
\begin{ubuntu}
 whoami |\LR| root
 id |\LR| uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
 hostname |\LR| ubuntu
 _
\end{ubuntu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM/IMPROVEMENT**. After answering [this follow-up question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/518202/tcbuselibrary-redefining-every-listing-line?noredirect=1&lq=1) I feel that the above is unnecessarily complicated. One can just define a command, `\StartConsole`, that removes the prompt, and a command `\SU` that installs a certain prompt. This command can be used e.g. as in

```
\SU{user=bob,host=remotehost,color=cyan}
```

which changes the prompt to

```
 bob@remotehost:~#
```

Even better, one can install styles for users. For instance,

```
\pgfkeys{/ubuntu/.cd,bob/.style={user=bob,host=remotehost,color=cyan}}
```

followed by

```
\SU{bob}
```

will achieve the same.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,url}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse,listings}

\begin{document}

\newtcblisting{ubuntu}{colback=violet!50!black,
colupper=white,colframe=gray!65!black,listing only,
listing options={style=tcblatex,language=sh,escapeinside=``,},
title={\textcolor{orange}{\Huge{$\bullet$}}{\textcolor{gray}{\Huge{$\bullet\bullet$}}}},
every listing line={\MyUbuntuPrompt}}
\pgfkeys{/ubuntu/.cd,
user/.code={\gdef\MyUbuntuUser{#1}},user={},
host/.code={\gdef\MyUbuntuHost{#1}},host={},
color/.code={\gdef\MyUbuntuColor{#1}},color=white,
prompt char/.code={\gdef\MyUbuntuPromptChar{#1}},prompt char=\#,
root/.style={user=root,host=ubuntu,color=lime,prompt char=\#},
bob/.style={user=bob,host=remotehost,color=cyan},
}
\newcommand{\SU}[1]{\pgfkeys{/ubuntu/.cd,#1}%
\gdef\MyUbuntuPrompt{\textcolor{\MyUbuntuColor}{\small\ttfamily\bfseries \MyUbuntuUser@\MyUbuntuHost{\textcolor{white}:}\textcolor{cyan!60}{\url{~}}{\textcolor{white}\MyUbuntuPromptChar} }}}
\newcommand{\StartConsole}{\gdef\MyUbuntuPrompt{}}

\SU{user=root,host=ubuntu,color=lime}
\begin{ubuntu}
whoami `\StartConsole`
root `\SU{root}` 
id `\StartConsole` 
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)`\SU{root}`
hostname `\StartConsole`
ubuntu`\SU{root}`
ssh bob@remotehost`\StartConsole`
bob@remotehost's`\ `password:
Linux remotehost 2.6.32-5-686 #1 SMP Sun Sep 23 09:49:36 UTC 2012 i686
You have mail.
Last login: Wed Oct 16 01:12:35 2012 from localhost
`\SU{bob}`
whoami`\StartConsole`
bob`\SU{bob}`
_
\end{ubuntu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

User names with special characters also work without problems. The fat underscore is borrowed from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48633).

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,url,tikzlings}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse,listings}

\begin{document}

\newtcblisting{ubuntu}{colback=violet!50!black,
colupper=white,colframe=gray!65!black,listing only,
listing options={style=tcblatex,language=sh,escapeinside=``,},
title={\textcolor{orange}{\Huge{$\bullet$}}{\textcolor{gray}{\Huge{$\bullet\bullet$}}}},
every listing line={\MyUbuntuPrompt},enhanced,
overlay={\begin{tcbinvclipframe}
\penguin[shift={([xshift=2cm,yshift=-0.8cm]frame.north)}]
\end{tcbinvclipframe}}}
\pgfkeys{/ubuntu/.cd,
user/.code={\gdef\MyUbuntuUser{#1}},user={},
host/.code={\gdef\MyUbuntuHost{#1}},host={},
color/.code={\gdef\MyUbuntuColor{#1}},color=white,
prompt char/.code={\gdef\MyUbuntuPromptChar{#1}},prompt char=\#,
root/.style={user=root,host=ubuntu,color=lime,prompt char=\#},
bob/.style={user=bob,host=remotehost,color=cyan},
cat/.style={user={schroedingers\char`_cat},host=burrow,color=magenta,prompt char=\$}
}
\newcommand{\SU}[1]{\pgfkeys{/ubuntu/.cd,#1}%
\gdef\MyUbuntuPrompt{\textcolor{\MyUbuntuColor}{\small\ttfamily\bfseries \MyUbuntuUser@\MyUbuntuHost{\textcolor{white}:}\textcolor{cyan!60}{\url{~}}{\textcolor{white}\MyUbuntuPromptChar} }}}
\newcommand{\StartConsole}{\gdef\MyUbuntuPrompt{}}

\SU{user=root,host=ubuntu,color=lime}
\begin{ubuntu}
whoami `\StartConsole`
root `\SU{root}` 
id `\StartConsole` 
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)`\SU{root}`
hostname `\StartConsole`
ubuntu`\SU{root}`
ssh cat@burrow`\StartConsole`
bob@remotehost's`\ `password:
Linux remotehost 2.6.32-5-686 #1 SMP Sun Sep 23 09:49:36 UTC 2012 i686
You have mail.
Last login: Wed Oct 16 01:12:35 2012 from localhost
`\SU{cat}`
whoami`\StartConsole`
schroedingers_cat`\SU{cat}`
_
\end{ubuntu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The penguin must have seen the many occurrences of the word "Ubuntu" here.

Comment: Can you explain what you did? I see you added `escapeinside=||`, which is obvious, but i've never used these guys: `\newlength{\Lind}
\setbox0\hbox{\small\ttfamily\bfseries root@}
\setlength{\Lind}{\the\dimexpr\wd0+1pt}
\newcommand{\LR}{\\\hspace*{-\Lind}}`.

I mean, I can see what you've done and why in a broad sense (simply escaping `\newline` & `\\ ` seems to leave indents & extra whitespace), but I don't understand how it works. Rather than just copying you blindly, it would be valuable to know the details so I can learn to solve this kind of problem on my own next time.

Comment: I did try to explain what I did but I am lacking fundamental information on what you do not understand in the explanation. This is a recurring problem, and there is a [nice video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dp4dpeJVDxs) explaining it. All I can say is that `\\` corresponds to a carriage return and `\hspace*{-\Lind}` undoes the indent because `\hspace` generates some space but if its argument is negative it undoes it. I will be happy to explain differently if I know what part of my explanation you have trouble with.

Comment: Well, it's hard to say. I mean, you solved the problem when I couldn't. I don't really know what it is that I ought to know. You do; I'm likely to ask the wrong questions. But I'm not the only one reading it either, don't forget. **A]** These are all new to me: `\Lind`, `\setbox0`, `\hbox`, `\setlength`, `\the\dimexpr\wd0+1pt`, `\\\hspace*{-\Lind}`. Is this stuff that everyone knows? **B]** Seems `\Lind` is some undefined numerical value? **C]** Why is this argument given: `{\small\ttfamily\bfseries root@}`? Some of the command names are self-explanatory, but how to use them is not so obvious.

Comment: @voices `\setbox0\hbox{<something>}` is a standard trick to measure the width of something. So I measure the width and store it in a dimension that I called `\Lind` for no special reason, you could use `\IdontknowhowIwanttocallthislength` instead. `\the\dimexpr` allows us to add lengths, which I used to increase the length by 1pt. The argument is just copied from `every listing line` because the font information does alter the width.

Comment: So basically `\setbox0` defines a variable like `\def`? and `\the\dimexpr` is the same as `\the\numexpr`? And `\hbox` does.. something. Measures the horizontal width of it's argument maybe? The width of what what exactly; why is it only `root@`? And `\hspace` is equal to the horizontal width of the page?

Comment: @voices At some level, these are very good analogies except for \hspace, which inserts a space that is given by its argument.  (I am only on my cell phone now.)

Comment: Thanks for your help on this one. Do you think it's possible to put the input and output on separate lines; just for ease of reading and writing? You can see the code in this followup question quickly gets hard to read: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/518202/165801

Comment: @voices Yes. There is a simple trick: you can just change the prompt on the fly. I wrote an answer for that.

Comment: @voices I added a version using pgf keys which simplifies things IMO.

Comment: @voices I added a way to change the prompt char to the lowest example.

Comment: This is great. It would be a great package: thousands of TeX users want to write explanations of how to use software packages at the command prompt.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay Actually, I think the most useful approach may be to write a `tcolorbox` library that does these. I am neither competent enough to write something that has the standards of `tcolorbox` nor do I want to dump this request on its author, but if somebody knows a way of asking Thomas in a polite way, that would be great. It is not absolutely inconceivable that he may find something from here useful, but most likely he will have better ways.

Comment: Would it be possible to extend this so that your path can change? RIght now it's always `~`

Comment: Nice work, but I encountered a small problem provided, in my opinion, by the escaping | symbol. How can I enter commands like `cat /etc/passwd | sed ...` ?