# tcbuselibrary: redefining "every listing line"

Tags: listings, tcolorbox, code, terminal-output

This is following up to an earlier question:
 [Drawing Realistic Linux Command Shell Windows with tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/517976/165801)

---

I'd like to be able to create something like this:

[image]

---

For the most part I can, but I can't redefine the prompt and colours, etc. So basically I want to be able to define multiple `every listing line` values or to somehow redefine it arbitrarily at certain points. For example:

**alice**

```
every listing line={\textcolor{magenta}{\small\ttfamily\bfseries{alice@localhost{\textcolor{black}:}\textcolor{cyan!60}{\url{~}}{\textcolor{black}\$ }}}}}
```

**bob**

```
every listing line={\textcolor{cyan}{\small\ttfamily\bfseries{bob@remotehost{\textcolor{black}:}\textcolor{cyan!60}{\url{~}}{\textcolor{black}\$ }}}}}
```

---

**mwe**

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,url,xcolor}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse,minted,listings}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\newlength{\USER}
\setbox0\hbox{\small\ttfamily\bfseries ....}
\setlength{\USER}{\the\dimexpr\wd0+1pt}
\newcommand{\stdout}{\\\hspace*{-\USER}}    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\newtcblisting{macos}{size=small,halign title=flush left,
title={\textcolor{red!62}{\huge\ttfamily\bfseries{$\bullet\,$}\textcolor{orange!52!yellow}{\huge\ttfamily\bfseries{$\bullet\,$}\textcolor{green!80!black}{\huge\ttfamily\bfseries{$\bullet\,$}}}}}, 
colback=white,colupper=black,colframe=gray!25,listing only,
listing options={style=tcblatex,language=sh,escapeinside=``},
every listing line={\textcolor{magenta}{\small\ttfamily\bfseries{alice@localhost{\textcolor{black}:}\textcolor{cyan!60}{\url{~}}{\textcolor{black}\# }}}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%        
\begin{macos}
ssh bob@remotehost`\stdout`bob@remotehost's`\ `password:`\stdout`Linux remotehost 2.6.32-5-686 #1 SMP Sun Sep 23 09:49:36 UTC 2012 i686`\stdout`You have mail.`\stdout`Last login: Wed Oct 16 01:12:35 2012 from localhost`\stdout``\stdout`bob@remotehost:~$ _
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%        
\end{macos}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply change the prompt on the fly. This is done by three commands

- `\StartAlice`, after which the prompt becomes `alice@localhost:~$`,
- `\StartBob`, after which the prompt becomes `bob@localhost:~$`,
- `\StartConsole` which leads to no prompt.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,url,xcolor}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse,minted,listings}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\newtcblisting{macos}{size=small,halign title=flush left,
title={\textcolor{red!62}{\huge\ttfamily\bfseries{$\bullet\,$}\textcolor{orange!52!yellow}{\huge\ttfamily\bfseries{$\bullet\,$}\textcolor{green!80!black}{\huge\ttfamily\bfseries{$\bullet\,$}}}}}, 
colback=white,colupper=black,colframe=gray!25,listing only,
listing options={style=tcblatex,language=sh,escapeinside=``},
every listing line={\myprompt}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%        
\newcommand\myaliceprompt{\textcolor{magenta}{\small\ttfamily\bfseries{alice@localhost{\textcolor{black}:}\textcolor{cyan!60}{\url{~}}{\textcolor{black}\$ }}}}
\newcommand\mybobprompt{\textcolor{cyan}{\small\ttfamily\bfseries{bob@remotehost{\textcolor{black}:}\textcolor{cyan!60}{\url{~}}{\textcolor{black}\$ }}}}
\newcommand\myconsoleprompt{}
\newcommand{\StartBob}{\gdef\myprompt{\mybobprompt}}
\newcommand{\StartAlice}{\gdef\myprompt{\myaliceprompt}}
\newcommand{\StartConsole}{\gdef\myprompt{\myconsoleprompt}}    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\StartAlice
\begin{macos}
ssh bob@remotehost`\StartConsole`
bob@remotehost's`\ `password:
Linux remotehost 2.6.32-5-686 #1 SMP Sun Sep 23 09:49:36 UTC 2012 i686
You have mail.
Last login: Wed Oct 16 01:12:35 2012 from localhost
`\StartBob`
whoami`\StartConsole`
bob
\end{macos}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%            
\end{document}
```

[image]
A perhaps more structured way is to only define an `\SU` command to switch. Then e.g. `\SU{alice@localhost}` changes the prompt to `alice@localhost:~$`, and `\StartConsole` works as above.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,url,xcolor}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse,minted,listings}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\newtcblisting{macos}{size=small,halign title=flush left,
title={\textcolor{red!62}{\huge\ttfamily\bfseries{$\bullet\,$}\textcolor{orange!52!yellow}{\huge\ttfamily\bfseries{$\bullet\,$}\textcolor{green!80!black}{\huge\ttfamily\bfseries{$\bullet\,$}}}}}, 
colback=white,colupper=black,colframe=gray!25,listing only,
listing options={style=tcblatex,language=sh,escapeinside=``},
every listing line={\myprompt}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%        
\newcommand{\SU}[1]{\gdef\myprompt{\textcolor{magenta}{\small\ttfamily\bfseries{#1{\textcolor{black}:}\textcolor{cyan!60}{\url{~}}{\textcolor{black}\$ }}}}}
\newcommand{\StartConsole}{\gdef\myprompt{}}    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\SU{alice@localhost}
\begin{macos}
ssh bob@remotehost`\StartConsole`
bob@remotehost's`\ `password:
Linux remotehost 2.6.32-5-686 #1 SMP Sun Sep 23 09:49:36 UTC 2012 i686
You have mail.
Last login: Wed Oct 16 01:12:35 2012 from localhost
`\SU{bob@remotehost}`
whoami`\StartConsole`
bob
\end{macos}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%            
\end{document}
```

Comment: @voices The lower part of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/517976/165801 allows you to change the color.

Comment: very nice. so can we use both styles in the same document? the first might be the purple ubuntu screen, then the next part might switch to the mac style and so on. I'm doing a bit of a writeup. There's lots of switching back and forth between different consoles, different computers, different usernames, etc. It's very effective, it looks great and very easy to read with the different visual queues, but having a little trouble getting it all to mesh together. Do I have to redefine everything, or should it all flow together nicely?

Comment: @voices Now I do not understand the question. Can't you just define different listings style like `macos-1`, `macos-2`, ... `ubuntu-1` and so on, and then switch the styles by saying `\begin{macos-1}... \end{macos-1}`,  `\begin{macos-2}... \end{macos-2}` and so on?

Comment: up until this point i could do that with `\newtcblisting{...}`.

Comment: @voices You can still introduce as many `\newtcblisting{...}`s as you wish. As long as you have `every listing line={\myprompt}` in them they will collaborate with these tricks.

Comment: but it's all ubuntu this and ubuntu that. do i have to define these again? actually i think the problem is it doesn't like me using an underscore in one of the new usernames. Try changing `bob` or `root` to `user_name` or something like that. You'll see what I mean.

Comment: @voices No. You can define a style `ubuntu base`, which contains all the common elements, and just add the specific elements to the individual styles.

Comment: @voices Yes, this is an issue, and the answer is not really prepared for this. You can make it work by using `cat/.style={user={schroedingers\noexpand\textunderscore cat},host=burrow,color=magenta}` in the other answer.

Comment: that's fine. it works well. one last thing: the final character. how do you change the final character? sometimes it's `\$`, sometimes it's `\#`. small but important distinction.