ubuntu terminal emulator: how to remove horizontal translucent lines
I was using this from Alan Xiang's Blog to emulate an ubuntu terminal in latex. However, with multiple lines, some translucent horizontal lines appear, that make it less attractive to look at. I would like to remove them, so that only the background color appears. I leave a print of what these horizontal lines are.
This is the macro I am using:
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mymauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{terminalbgcolor}{HTML}{330033}
\definecolor{terminalrulecolor}{HTML}{000099}
\newcommand{\lstconsolestyle}{
\lstset{
    backgroundcolor=\color{terminalbgcolor},
    basicstyle=\color{white}\fontfamily{fvm}\footnotesize\selectfont,
    breakatwhitespace=false,  
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    commentstyle=\color{mygreen},
    deletekeywords={...},
    escapeinside={\%*}{*)},
    extendedchars=true,
    frame=single%none,%single
    keepspaces=true,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    %language=none,
    morekeywords={*,...},
    numbers=none,
    numbersep=5pt,
    framerule=0pt,%2pt 0.5pt
    numberstyle=\color{mygray}\tiny\selectfont,
    rulecolor=\color{terminalbgcolor},
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    stepnumber=2,
    stringstyle=\color{mymauve},
    tabsize=2,
}

Thanks in advance!!

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Have you checked with different pdf viewers to verify that this isn't a viewer issue?

As an alternative approach, you could use a tcblisting from the tcolorbox package and use this to set the background colour.

related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/517976/drawing-realistic-linux-command-shell-windows-with-tcolorbox

There is the package termsim which you should have a look at.
