# Underscore is shorter for ttfamily

Tags: typewriter

I'm struggling with the problem with underscores in a mono font.
It looks like it is shorter than other symbols.
For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\ttfamily
Test \\
.------------.-------------.--------------.\\
\ |\ abcdefghig\ |\ klmnopqrstu\ |\ vwxyzabcdefg\ | \\
.------------.-------------.--------------.\\
\ |\ abc[e]ghig\ |\ klm[o]qrstu\ |\ vwxyza[c]efg\ | \\
.------------.-------------.--------------.\\
\ |\ dfi\_cke[x]\ |\ dfi\_cs\_n[x]\ |\ dfi\_act\_n[x]\ | \\
.------------.-------------.--------------.
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: The result]

As you can see, the last line (with underscores) is shifted left. How I can make the

P.S. No, I can't use a native table - this is a user-generated piece I have to insert as-is.
P.S.S. The `verbatim` is not an option because it is not working inside `multicolumn`

Comment: I suggest you to put everything inside a `\begin{verbatim}\end{verbatim}` and then you don't need to insert a lot o slashes.

Comment: (somewhat related question: [characters - Underscores in words (text) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48632/underscores-in-words-text))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of `\_`, you can use `\string_`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ttfamily
Test \\
.------------.-------------.--------------.\\
\ |\ abcdefghig\ |\ klmnopqrstu\ |\ vwxyzabcdefg\ | \\
.------------.-------------.--------------.\\
\ |\ abc[e]ghig\ |\ klm[o]qrstu\ |\ vwxyza[c]efg\ | \\
.------------.-------------.--------------.\\
\ |\ dfi\string_cke[x]\ |\ dfi\string_cs\string_n[x]\ |\ dfi\string_act\string_n[x]\ | \\
.------------.-------------.--------------.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works as expected.

Answer (score 7):

The most natural way is to use `verbatim` (see below). But let's explain a bit what happens first.

In `OT1` encoding, `\textunderscore`, which `\_` relies on, is faked using a rule (it is not a character of the current font). Switching to `T1` encoding by adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` makes `\_` use an actual character of the font selected by `\ttfamily`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\ttfamily
Test \\
.------------.-------------.--------------.\\
\ |\ abcdefghig\ |\ klmnopqrstu\ |\ vwxyzabcdefg\ | \\
.------------.-------------.--------------.\\
\ |\ abc[e]ghig\ |\ klm[o]qrstu\ |\ vwxyza[c]efg\ | \\
.------------.-------------.--------------.\\
\ |\ dfi\_cke[x]\ |\ dfi\_cs\_n[x]\ |\ dfi\_act\_n[x]\ | \\
.------------.-------------.--------------.
\end{document}
```

[image]

The underscores now have the same size as other characters. However, as pointed out by Barbara Beeton, consecutive hyphens in non-verbatim mode combine into ligatures (en-dash with `--`, em-dash with `---`). If we turn off ligatures—which is one of the things that `verbatim` does—then all lines have the expected length:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\ttfamily\makeatletter\@noligs\makeatother
Test \\
.------------.-------------.--------------.\\
\ |\ abcdefghig\ |\ klmnopqrstu\ |\ vwxyzabcdefg\ | \\
.------------.-------------.--------------.\\
\ |\ abc[e]ghig\ |\ klm[o]qrstu\ |\ vwxyza[c]efg\ | \\
.------------.-------------.--------------.\\
\ |\ dfi\_cke[x]\ |\ dfi\_cs\_n[x]\ |\ dfi\_act\_n[x]\ | \\
.------------.-------------.--------------.
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Practically, using `verbatim` in such situations is more natural, though. The above examples were just to help understand what happens behind the scenes. Thus, what I would do here is this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
Test
.-------------.-------------.--------------.
 | abcdefghig | klmnopqrstu | vwxyzabcdefg |
.-------------.-------------.--------------.
 | abc[e]ghig | klm[o]qrstu | vwxyza[c]efg |
.-------------.-------------.--------------.
 | dfi_cke[x] | dfi_cs_n[x] | dfi_act_n[x] |
.-------------.-------------.--------------.
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image: With verbatim]

Note that since “Test” is inside the `verbatim` environment, it doesn't get paragraph indentation in this case.

## Technical details

For those interested, the implementation of `\textunderscore` in `OT1` encoding, obtained with `\tracingmacros=1\tracingonline=1`, does:

```latex
\leavevmode \kern .06em\vbox{\hrule width .3em}
```

whereas in `T1` encoding, in the end, it is a simple `\char"5F` (thus, a command that adds to the current list a character box containing the character with hexadecimal code 5F in the current font).

Comment: Sorry, not.  The hyphens have ligatured into en-dashes, which seem to be the same length as hyphens.  `verbatim` really is the best (most reliable) way to go.

Comment: That is true and a good point, but I was answering what was happening with the underscores, not the hyphens (as per the question). Oh well...

Comment: @barbara beeton I've added an example that turns ligatures off.

Comment: Yes, the question stated that the underscores weren't matching in width, but I'm pretty sure that the OP wasn't aware that something else could happen to throw off the (intended) alignment.

Comment: Good addition.  I like it, even if it's not the approach I'd normally use.

Comment: I've completed the answer in a way that, I hope, makes it more suitable for the OP. Thanks for your valuable feedback, @barbarabeeton.

Comment: Thank you. But I can't use `verbatim` because it is not working in `multicolumn`

Comment: Ah, I see. That would have been worth mentioning in the first version of the question... My solution with `\@noligs` (possibly in the form of `\csname @noligs\endcsname`) should be usable in these new conditions, though, and has the advantage of working correctly in the modern `T1` encoding (the hyphens in Werner's solution are only as you expect them because it uses `OT1` encoding).

Comment: *\textunderscore, which \_ relies on, is faked using a rule* which is presumably also why the stroke width is so different as well

Comment: @ChrisH Sure. According to the *Technical details* at the end of my answer and the TeXbook p. 221, the rule width (actually, its `height`) is `0.4pt`. No idea how much it is for the font used here, but for a start, this `0.4pt` doesn't depend on the font in use.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `verbatim`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
   Test
.------------.-------------.--------------.
| abcdefghig | klmnopqrstu | vwxyzabcdefg | 
.------------.-------------.--------------.
| abc[e]ghig | klm[o]qrstu | vwxyza[c]efg | 
.------------.-------------.--------------.
| dfi_cke[x] | dfi_cs_n[x] | dfi_act_n[x] | 
.------------.-------------.--------------.
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can improve this answer by explaining the difference between `\ttfamily` and `verbatim`..  (`verbatim` is definitely the way to go,; similarly `\verb` for short strings.`

Comment: `verbatim` is not an option - it is not working inside `mulicolumn`