# Define \textunderscore to mimic look of standard underscore

Tags: text, typewriter, catcodes

I noticed that the look of the underscore `_` differs greatly from the look of `\textunderscore`

How can I redefine `\textunderscore` to look like the standard underscore of the set font? I want to avoid changing the catcode, so redefining it seems to be the best option to me.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\catcode`\_11%

\begin{document}

{\ttfamily
\textunderscore _ 
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not a direct answer to your query, but possibly still of relevance: If you run `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` *before* `\catcode`\_11%`, the two underscore characters turn out to be the same. Likewise, if you omit `\catcode`\_11%` and type `\ttfamily \textunderscore \_`, both characters turn out be the same again, but now of the lighter, OT1 variety

Comment: do you have to use OT1-encoding?

Comment: The only reason for supporting OT1 a legacy 7-bit encoding is backwards compatibility, so it is what it is, you get different results in T1 or TU encodings which all current documents should use.

Comment: If you insist on using OT1 encoding (or for educational purpose) see also [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/643285/250119)  ("To make it "smart"..." section) -- also mentioned there it's simpler to just use `\_` instead of `\textunderscore`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\fontencoding{TU}\selectfont
\textrm{[\_][\string_]} \texttt{[\_][\string_]}

\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont
\textrm{[\_][\string_]} \texttt{[\_][\string_]}

\fontencoding{OT1}\selectfont
\textrm{[\_][\string_]} \texttt{[\_][\string_]}
\end{document}
```

Ideally `\textunderscore` (`\_`)  would simply access the `_` character in the current font, and that is what happens in encodings that have `_`. The original TeX encoding as used in the `minimal` class example in the question does not have `_` at all, the slot is taken with the accent character as seen in the image. Just the tt font has `_` to allow verbatim, but for OT1 LaTeX defines `\_` as a tex-drawn rule independent of the font.

Comment: One addition: `\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont`does not work if put into the preamble.

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen the document default font is set at begin document, so that setting will be undone unless you make the document default T1,  the usual way in the preamble is `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`