# Underscore notation trouble in latex

Tags: math-mode, fonts, equations, symbols, underscore

Which command should I use to get the shorter version of underscore, on picture below. I tried everything _ , {_}, \underscore, \textunderscore, but I always get the longer version of underscore - shown on other image. I even tried \underscore{ } and \underline{ }, but if I use this two expressions, my undercore is not lined with text, but it is below the text.

Please help!¨I am losing my mind!

I forgot to mention that I even used all commands noted above with $...$, but no luck either.

[image] [image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[slovene]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}
    \textbf{latex}\_\textbf{Priimek}\_\textbf{Ime}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I get you right, you can try `$latex_{veryveryverylongtext}$`?!

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. :(

Comment: This type of question IMO is very hard to answer without a MWE. The reason for your type-setting issues may or may not be caused by any package or combination of packages you are using. Would you be able to provide a MWE?

Comment: I hope it helps.

Comment: @EdwardHenryBrenner Am I getting you right and you want two underscores?

Comment: Yes I want two "short" underscores.

Comment: @EdwardHenryBrenner Is this what you want? `$\mathbf{latex_{Priimek_{Ime}}}$`

Comment: No. I will add another picture to question description to explain better what i want.

Comment: Picture added to question description... at the bottom

Comment: @EdwardHenryBrenner Now I got you. Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48632/underscores-in-words-text/48633 answer your question?

Comment: Apparently underscores in text are quite a hot topic and have been covered extensively in other questions you may want to browse. More specifically I would refer you to this answer to a similar(?) question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239191/118712

Comment: I will look it up. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine the size of the underscore by using
`\renewcommand{\_}{\textscale{.5}{\textunderscore}}`
You need to load `\usepackage{relsize}` in your preamble

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[slovene]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{relsize}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\_}{\textscale{.5}{\textunderscore}}
\textbf{latex}\_\textbf{Priimek}\_\textbf{Ime}

\end{document}
```

[image]