# Disable underscore in text mode causing automatic switch to math mode

Tags: math-mode, underscore, text-mode

Underscores in text mode are common, but these trigger automatic math mode and then I have to go find all the underscores and escape them.

**Goal:**
Is there a way to disable underscores in text-mode causing automatic conversion to math mode? In other words, this would mean no need to escape underscores in text mode.

I did a quick Google search using this exact title + 'latex', but no relevant results found.

Comment: You probably come across that question already, but see this exact answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/321542/250119

Comment: @user202729 ahhh.; I didn't realize the desired answer would be all the way below. Thanks!

Comment: You could use `underscore` package but I think you are starting from the wrong premise. "Underscores in text mode are common" Underscores  essentially never occur in normal text, which is why it was a free character available as a math subscript character. If you are setting computer program variable names or other special forms, naturally you can locally make `_` a normal letter, but nothing special about `_`,  you might want `$aa_b` and `%xxx_yyy` also to be text so would need `$` and `%` treated similarly which `underscore` package will not do.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the kind reply. I agree, that makes sense. I like the local solution of making it a ‘normal letter’.