# Underscore in listing color

Tags: color, listings

How to make this code works:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{s}{escapechar={|}}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=s]
foo
|\color{red}{bar_42}|
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Without having to add a `\` before the `_` ?

I have a large portion of code to put into my listing with lots of `_` and I don't want to manually add a `\` everywhere.

Comment: Using the `underscore` package has some limitations (like you can't have _ in filenames). A solution to this is changing the category code of the underscore. Corresponding [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386646/219947).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load the package `underscore`. With that package, the character `_` is available in text mode of LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{underscore}

\lstdefinestyle{s}{escapechar={|}}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=s]
foo
|\color{red}{bar_42}|
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thanks! you made my day :)