# \input function doesn't work: trying to include contents of external text file

Tags: external-files, text, include

I want to include the contents of an external text file into my LaTeX document. I've tried `\input{./message}`, but all I get is an error containing the very last line of the text file:

```
(./message.txt
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.13 Truly yours_
                 
? x
No pages of output.
Transcript written on new-years.log.
```

For clarity, I don't want the contents of the text file to be included with any specific format, but rather undergo the same format as is specified for the rest of the document. In other words, I just want the content of the text file to be included as normal text, as though it had been copy-pasted into my LaTeX document. (The reason I'm not copy-pasting is that it would greatly simplify the layout of my LaTeX document if I could import the content from text files directly, as well as make it easier to modify, for me.)

Comment: To include `_` in document you need `\_`. [characters - Underscores in words (text) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48632/underscores-in-words-text/643285#643285) ("how to type _" is **not** what is asked there thus the answers look a bit weird)

Comment: Is the external file name `message.tex` or `message.txt`?

Comment: your log shows the input worked. you would get the same error if you put `truly yours_` in the main file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log

```
(./message.txt
```

confirms that the `\input` did work as you expected.

The input file text is being processed as if it were in the main file.

In this case it has a syntax error, you would see the same from:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Truly yours_

\end{document}
```

which gives

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.7 Truly yours_
                
?
```

A trailing `_` seems rather odd, perhaps you want to simply delete it, but if you do want `_` in the output, use `\_` or if you want to read the file with `_` locally a normal character not a math subscript use

```
{\catcode`\_=12 \input{message.txt}}
```

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

{\catcode`\_=12 
Truly yours_
}

\end{document}
```

Produces

[image]

Comment: I wonder if the `_` is the beginning of a signature line.  In that case, OP should look into hrule or rule.