# Escape "> and <"

Tags: symbols, punctuation

I have the following piece of text which I want to output literally: `<<"Welcome">>`. However it's converted to those funky quotations. I've been trying all sorts of things with `\` mostly but to no avail.

`\verb=!<<"Welcome">>!` kind of works, or gets the job done, but then it loses all other formatting (font face, size, etc.) as well.

Comment: See also [Less than symbol (<) appears as upside down](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2369/less-than-symbol-appears-as-upside-down).

Comment: @stephan, your \! does not appear..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A quick solution would be to use inline math mode: ``` $<<$``Welcome''$>>$ ```

**edit:** if you want to preserve formatting, have you considered `\textgreater` and `\textless` ?

Comment: No I haven't, but I'll google what they are about!

Answer (score 14):

I don't think the less-than and greater-than signs are that pretty here.  You might try instead:

- ``` $\langle\langle$``Welcome''$\rangle\rangle$ ``` for angle brackets that are narrower and taller than the mathematical relations.
- ``` \guillemotleft``Welcome''\guillemotright ``` for french quotation marks.  Make sure you also have `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in the preamble.

[image]

To be honest I don't think any of those look that pretty, but it is what you asked for. `:-D`

Comment: And `$\ll$`, `$\gg$`

Comment: @Leo Liu: good one.  I added it to my answer.

Comment: It's a code listing. I have pretty much no control over what it says and I need to display it. Thanks though, I learned a lot!

Answer (score 8):

This may be what you want:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\guillemotleft``Welcome''\guillemotright

\end{document}
```

---

For code listing, you can use `listings` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fixed,
  literate={<<}{\guillemotleft}1 {>>}{\guillemotright}1
}

\begin{document}

\lstinline!<<"Welcome">>!

\end{document}
```

You can modify the `literate` as you wish.

Comment: Looks pretty sweet and I salute you for you fu! Unfortunately, it's a code listing. But I will keep this in mind!

Comment: @Till: You didn't mention that. My previous solution use `lisings` package especially for code listing. But I thought it's normal text and deleteted it. You may have a look at the edit history of this question (click the time after `edited`).

Comment: I recovered the previous solution.

Comment: Thanks for editing and extending your answer. I'll make sure to provide more details next time.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use brackets around one of your `<` or `>` symbol to avoid merging it with the second one. For example `<{<}My text{>}>`.

Comment: This implies `<<` necessarily merges. Why is that?