# Url is not displayed correctly

Tags: urls

I am using some big faculty LaTeX template for my thesis, so I do not really know, which packages I am supposed to mention here ...

Anyway, I am trying to write some urls.

I write them like

```
\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask}
```

But the result in the PDF is

```
¡http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask¿
```

What can be wrong? How can I get rid of those marks?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. For errors like these it is best to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates them. This way people can compile it by themselves and also test their solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does your template redefine `\url` such that its output should look like `<https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask>` (including the angular brackets)? In this case the font encoding might be wrong. Try adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to the preamble (or use `\textless` and `\textgreater` in the definition of `\url`).

See also [Why do the less than symbol (<) and the greater than symbol (>) appear wrong as upside down exclamation (¡) or question mark (¿)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2369/less-than-symbol-appears-as-upside-down).

Comment: thank you, `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` remove `!?` but it replaces them with `<,>` ... is there any way to have only url? or is it typographically wrong?

Comment: @relaxxx: As a default `\url` doesn't add anything around the text. So something in your document changed the default behaviour - perhaps by redefining the `\UrlLeft` and `\UrlRight` commands mentioned by egreg. That's the problem when using "big" templates. They can do a lot of unusual things.

Answer (score 7):

You are probably writing `<\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask}>`; the standard setup for LaTeX fonts has `¡` and `¿` in place of `<` and `>`. In order to get typewriter `<` and `>` use `\texttt{<}` and `\texttt{>}`. Those characters in the normal font would be wrong anyway.

The documentation of the url package shows a trick for having those characters automatically: put

```
\DeclareUrlCommand\url{\def\UrlLeft{<}\def\UrlRight{>}\urlstyle{tt}}
```

in the preamble of your document.

Comment: I am not writing `<...>` i have just `text \url{} text`, but when I try copy `!url?` from my pdf, it copy it in `<url>` format