# Why is pdflatex not recognizing my > symbol?

Tags: symbols

I have a `>` symbol in my LateX file. Specifically, I have the sentence:

```
Say I have n > 1 apples.
```

When compile my .tex document using pdflatex, I get a pdf with an upside-down question mark in place of the > symbol.

I checked this math guide for TeX and saw no special markup for `>`.
http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/short-math-guide/short-math-guide.pdf

What is going on?

Comment: That's an equation, so you should be using math mode by enclosing the text in `$...$`: `Say I have $n > 1$ apples`.

Comment: Thanks, how did pdflatex detect that I was in math mode?

Comment: For instance, I could have very well been writing a paragraph that happened to contain n > 1, right?

Comment: TeX doesn’t detect maths automatically. The author requests mathmode by writing `\( math \)` or `\[ math \]` when using LaTeX and `$ math $` or `$$ math $$` when using plain TeX.

Comment: @uli Actually PDFTeX will try and guess when you are in math mode, but it is really bad at it an will screw up when it does. As someone who forgets \( too often I've seen that error a few times >.>

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Related question: [Less than symbol (<) appears as upside down “!”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2369/less-than-symbol-appears-as-upside-down)

Short answers:

- Use the [fontenc](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontenc) package.
- Use math mode.
- Use the [fontspec](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf) package.
- Use `\textgreater`.  On older installations, you might need to load the `textcomp` package to enable it, but this is not necessary on recent versions.

This specific example should really be in math mode, since n is a variable. But for completeness:

```
\documentclass{article}
% comment out to see inverted question mark in place of > in ``Regular'' entry.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Say I have n > 1 apples (regular, with or without fontenc package).
\item Say I have \( n > 1 \) apples (math mode).
\item Say I have n \textgreater{} 1 apples (textcomp).
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, the math mode greater-than sign is a bit heavier than the text symbols.