# "Greater than" sign shows up as inverted question mark

Tags: math-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do the less than symbol (<) and the greater than symbol (>) appear wrong as upside down exclamation or question mark?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2369/why-do-the-less-than-symbol-and-the-greater-than-symbol-appear-wrong-as)

My question is in the title.

How can I write the greater than symbol? When I use the < off the keyboard, it appears on my PDF as an inverted question mark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use it as a math operator, you need to add `$` signs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$>$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `textcomp` package and the command `\textlangle` or `\textrangle`.