# beramono and texttt : angle brackets show as inverted exclamation mark and inverted question mark symbols (upside-down signs, like in spanish)

Tags: symbols, punctuation, font-encodings, brackets, beramono

Angle brackets `<` and `>` in `\texttt` render as inverted exclamation mark and inverted question mark (spanish punctuation marks):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beramono}
\begin{document}
\texttt{<>}
\end{document}
```

The above document renders the `<` and `>` characters as:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: This is intentionally a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2369/5699 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45539/5699 . After 10 minutes of googling and searching on TeX.SX I couldn't find either, so I decided to post this, hoping the terms will be easier to search for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Bera Mono fonts are not available in OT1 encoding, but only in T1; if you want to use them for typewriter type, you need `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

This should be clear from the shown warnings

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/fvm/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 4.
```

Correct example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{beramono}
\begin{document}
\texttt{<>}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wanted to avoid `T1` font encoding, because I thought it messed up copy-paste from the `PDF`s. After testing your answer, copy-paste (and the brackets) both seem to work fine, so my former issues must have been caused by something else.

Comment: FYI: I get this behaviour in an English document (not with beramono) without any warnings. `\usepackage{[T1]{fontenc}` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You have to also use the package `lmodern`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beramono}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\texttt{<>}
\end{document}
```

See [Why do the less than symbol (<) and the greater than symbol (>) appear wrong as upside down exclamation (¡) or question mark (¿)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2369/5699) and ["Greater than" sign shows up as inverted question mark](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45539/5699) for more details.

Comment: Well, you *don't* get Bera Mono as the typewriter font.