# Using < > symbols inside algorithmic

Tags: algorithms, math-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do the less than symbol (<) and the greater than symbol (>) appear wrong as upside down exclamation or question mark?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2369/why-do-the-less-than-symbol-and-the-greater-than-symbol-appear-wrong-as)

I have the following code

```
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[h]

\IF{$valuea$ < $valueb$}
    \STATE $valuer$ = 255
\ENDIF

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

but it is printed on pdf like this

```
if value_a¡valueb then
valuer = 255
end if
```

with the "¡" symbol instead of the "<" is there a way to force using "<" symbol?

Answer (score 5):

In pure answer to the question, any of the solutions provided by [Why do the less than symbol (`<`) and the greater than symbol (`>`) appear wrong as upside down exclamation or question mark?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2369/5764) will solve the problem. The easiest is probably to add

```
\usepackage{lmodern}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lmodern
```

to your document preamble. However...

...when using mathematical expressions, maintain the appropriate spacing by keeping the context mathematical. I would therefore suggest the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algorithmic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \IF{$\mbox{value}_a<\mbox{value}_b$}
      \STATE $\mbox{value}_r=255$
    \ENDIF
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

The operator spacing between the relations `<` and `=` will be kept better than using your original `$valuea$ < $valueb$`.

You may also consider transitioning to the more flexible [`algorithmicx` bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx).