# Problem printing some symbols accurately from a pgf plot table

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do the less than symbol (<) and the greater than symbol (>) appear wrong as upside down exclamation or question mark?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2369/why-do-the-less-than-symbol-and-the-greater-than-symbol-appear-wrong-as)

I'm trying to print symbols from my pgf plot table, which usually works fine. However, some signs, for example `<`and `>` aren't printed correctly. (In these particular cases, `<` is printed as an `¡` and `>` is printed as an `¿`.

I figure it can't be an encoding issue, since I'm typing the symbols are contained within my .tex file, so I guess it might have something to do with `<` and `>` being symbols normally used for syntax. However, putting an escape character before the symbol doesn't solve the problem.

Minimal non-working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma, header=false]{
<
}\mydata

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{0}\of\mydata
\node[draw=black] at (0,0) {\pgfplotsretval};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` should solve the issue. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2369/why-do-the-less-than-symbol-and-the-greater-than-symbol-appear-wrong-as

Comment: Thanks! I've voted to close my question as an exact duplicate.