# breaking line in gb4e

Tags: spacing, linguistics, gb4e

I use gb4e for my linguistic examples. When the example is long, gb4e breaks it into two lines (of the first and second, glossing, lines). However, I sometimes want to break it at a certain point. How can I do that? (I can't find any method in the gb4e document.)

A MWE is as follows. I'd like to break the line after the first occurrence of the word 'Mink'. If I do it in the second way, unwanted spaces appear between the lines. (I'm using xelatex.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex
\gll thu-mi-t-əm =k'wa Mink.  chichiya7-u-s =k'wa Mink te= c'estaya\\
go-RLT-CTR-PASS =QUOT Mink grandmother-PST-3POSS =QUOT Mink DET= knothole\\
\glt `Mink went towards it. The knothole was Mink's grandmother.'\\
\end{exe}

\begin{exe}
\ex
\gll thu-mi-t-əm =kʼwa Mink.\\
 go-RlL-CTR-PASS =QUOT Mink\\ 
\gll chichiya7-u-s =kʼwa Mink te= c'estaya\\
grandmother-PST-3POSS =QUOT Mink DET= knothole\\
\glt `Mink went towards it. The knothole was Mink's grandmother.'
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since you refer in your question to graphic elements that you would like improved, this is the type of question where an image of  your compiled MWE might be helpful.

Comment: I added an image to my original post.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of this question: [How can I indent the second line of a linguistic gloss with gb4e.sty?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115591)

Comment: OK. Thank you. I now see that I can solve this issue with \sn.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\def\Id#1{\vskip-.32cm\hskip.01cm\vtop{#1}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{exe}
        \ex
        \gll thu-mi-t-əm =kʼwa Mink.\\
        go-RlL-CTR-PASS =QUOT Mink\\
        \Id{%
        \gll chichiya7-u-s =kʼwa Mink te= c'estaya\\
        grandmother-PST-3POSS =QUOT Mink DET= knothole\\
        \glt `Mink went towards it. The knothole was Mink's grandmother.'%
         }  
      \end{exe}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The macro `\Id` changes the placement of the text using a `vtop` box, which overrides the `gb4e` package placement of that text.

And see related, the answers to: [*How can I indent the second line of a linguistic gloss with gb4e.sty*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115607/90087)

Comment: This is a pure hack, and not really practical as a solution. Since there are users of this package on the site, and it's a pretty specialized use, it might be more helpful to wait to see whether such users post solutions (or in this case, a duplicate.)

Comment: Point taken.  I changed the answer, made the \vtop box commands into a macro. Hopefully this makes it more practical.  I really don't know enough about the subject matter to even begin to form an opinion about whether this would fit the OP's needs, or whether it is really a duplicated of the question and answers you referenced.