# Smaller-than symbol ('<') in \text environment gets converted into upside down exclamation mark

Tags: amsmath

I want to typeset the `<` symbol in a string of text inside a math environment using the `\text` command from the `amsmath` package. However, for some reason it render something like

```
\text{<-wrt}
```

to

```
¡-wrt
```

Why does amsmath do that, and how can I stop it from 'interpreting' my text?

Comment: try \textless possible dupplicate with https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2369/why-do-the-less-than-symbol-and-the-greater-than-symbol-appear-wrong-as check the answer there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %%% <--- NOTE THIS

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \text{<-wrt}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```