# How to escape "->" (ASCII hyphen and greater than sign) in Latex

Tags: symbols, font-encodings

I have been trying to find a way to escape the "-" and ">" characters. I have looked at the `\verbatim{}` but this creates a new paragraph. As I have seen in other posts, my greater than sign shows up as an inverted question mark.

Thank You
Tom

Comment: `\verb|->|` or `\texttt{->}`? ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxA8H.png))

Comment: Or maybe `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`?  But if you want to write `->` to make an arrow, better use `$\to$` instead.  ([code](http://termbin.com/u0sjv), [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoGVZ.png)).

Comment: Your answer is probably solved by this: [Why do the less than symbol (`<`) and the greater than symbol (`>`) appear wrong as upside down exclamation (`¡`) or question mark (`¿`)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2369/5764)