# Use '<' character in lstlistings comment

Tags: listings

I have an issue where the '<' character in lstlistings appears as '¡' in the comments

How can I fix that please?

Comment: As always on this site, please provide a full but minimal example please. Then we know exactly what you are doing and can better provide advise.

Comment: my guess would be `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2369/why-do-the-less-than-symbol-and-the-greater-than-symbol-appear-wrong-as

Comment: Is this the kind of thing where using utf-8 encoding with `fontspec` would help?

Comment: @user202729 yes!