# How can I word-wrap LaTeX warning/error output?

Tags: errors, warnings, package-writing, documentclass-writing

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`hardwrap`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hardwrap)

In writing error messages and warnings for a package/class, I find it a pain to manually insert `\MessageBreak`s so that words don't get cruelly bisected because of TeX's `max_print_line` value (which typically is set to 79).  In some cases it's not possible to predict where the `\MessageBreak` should go because a macro in the warning/error message may be expanded to any length of string.

I'd like to have a macro that would take my warning/error message, expand it (so that any macros are expanded to plain strings), and insert `\MessageBreak`s in the appropriate places based on the value of `max_print_line` and LaTeX's per-line prefixes (`Package <XXX> Warning:` and similar).

(If the value of `max_print_line` can't be accessed from within TeX, I'd settle for just implementing a greedy word-wrap algorithm with the default line length values.)

**Follow-up:** [Will Robertson](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/179/will-robertson) and I created the [hardwrap](http://ctan.org/pkg/hardwrap) package to achieve the desired affect.

Comment: Not a solution so I'll just add it as a comment. If you haven't yet, you might consider diving into the `silence` package to see how it parses and conditionally removes selected error and warning lines from the output stream. (Apropos of nothing, it's one of my "must have" add-ins during draft document construction.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I never published the solution I wrote some time ago, but perhaps I should. Here's the link to an example: http://gist.github.com/605753 It's written in the plain old LaTeX programming style; it was a while ago so there are probably a few things in there that I now know how to do in a better way.

There are three examples where the broken text is typeset at different line lengths, and then a fourth example in which it is printed to the terminal. This isn't expandable (if it's possible, it would be difficult to say the least), but for many purposes that won't be an issue.

The code is undocumented, but you should be able to see the gist of it by ignoring everthing before `\begin{document}`. If you find it useful, I suggest we write a package for CTAN with some documentation and a better interface.

Comment: This looks like a good start (and the code aligns fairly well with what I had in mind). I'll shoot you an email to discuss my use cases in more detail. It'd be great if we could polish it up and post it to CTAN. I think others would find it useful as well. Thanks!

Comment: I see that you have now packaged this as the `hardwrap` package. Well done, and thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This is an orthogonal comment to my actual answer above; if you have TeX Live 2010, this will work in pdfTeX by default to access the `max_print_line` variable: (MiKTeX users will need to compile it with `-enable-pipes`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcount\maxprintline
\ifnum\pdfshellescape>0
  \maxprintline=\pdfprimitive\input"|kpsewhich -var-value=max_print_line"
\else
  \maxprintline=79 % default
\fi
The variable \verb|max_print_line| is \the\maxprintline.
\end{document}
```

It *won't* work if you have `-shell-escape` turned off entirely (hence the `\else` clause), but from my point of view there's no reason that restricted shell escape shouldn't always be activated (as it is by default).

This example could be re-written in a more general way to support XeTeX/LuaTeX use as well using the pdftexcmds package.

Comment: I had no idea `kpsewhich` was capable of doing this. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I didn't either until I just tried it `:)`

Comment: Will, would you know of any reasonably useful doco on `\pdfprimitive\input` (hopefully to the level of explaining why the `\input` control sequence needs the `|`  pipe before the child process command plus whatever else is going on)? I've hunted high and low down the usual web search laneways with absolutely no success. Even Google code search can't point to a single example line. I'm now doing a full TL2010 install in the vague hope that there'll be some pointers somewhere in there. Also, fyi, MikTeX (2.8 Windows, don't know about 2.9beta) `kpsewhich` balks on `-var-value=`. Aargh. :(

Comment: Hmm, let's see. I first heard about this feature via [MiKTeX 2.5](http://blog.miktex.org/post/2006/06/MiKTeX-25-Piped-input-and-output.aspx). I don't know how long it's been available in TeX Live; I only heard about it again [recently](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/how-to-insert-pipe-symbol-in-tex/1779#1779). Someone (sorry not me) should contribute some documentation to the TeX Live manual for it.

Comment: P.S. I don't run Windows any more so I can't help with the `kpsewhich` thing; I would hope (but am willing to be disappointed) that there's an equivalent way to do the same thing.

Comment: Will, thanks on both counts. The `\pdfprimitive` reading proved interesting but sadly, for multiple reasons too long to properly describe here, your code above won't run in a MikTeX environment (even when, too ambitiously, I replaced MikTeX's `kpsewhich.exe` with the one from TL2010). As for some other MikTeX executable outputting (vs consuming on its cmd line) a functional equivalent of `-var-value=max_print_line`, prepare to be disappointed, I'm sad to say. The take away is that your code remains fairly platform specific. Thanks again for your good help.

Comment: Oh well, too bad. I guess for now we can still use the `ifplatform` package to wrap the whole thing in `\ifwindows...\else\maxprintline=79 \fi`.

Comment: I should have been more careful with the way I phrased things. By platform, I meant MiKTeX v TeX Live (rather than Windows v other). I'll post a question on the miktex-users mailing list about how to programatically detect `max_print_line` and report back here if anything useful turns up. In any event, TL `kpsewhich` reads `max_print_line` from `texmf.cnf` (or something like that).  As this is a *static* value, your technique should be tested for correctness in cases where the user specifies the value at compile time, either by command line switches or in the 1st line of the `.tex` file.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get at `max_print_line` from within TeX, so that's out for a start. There are also issues with trying to write an automatic line-breaking algorithm. Will Robertson proposed some code a while ago for [`expl3`](http://ctan.org/pkg/expl3), but there are issues with TeX's expansion system. So I'm afraid that I think you are stuck having to do things by hand!

Comment: I suspected that accessing `max_print_line` might not be possible. Do you recall what problems Will encountered? (Feel free to point me to a mailing list thread, if one's available.)  Thanks for your response!