# Write to log without wrapping

Tags: tex-core, logging

I'd like to to generate some metadata in the log file that I can copy to another application.  But the log file is wrapped to 80 columns and I end up with newlines embedded in what I'm putting there.  Is there a way around this?

The two ways I know to write to the log file are `\message` and `\immediate\write17`.  But both of these have the same effect.  Is `\write17` a special filehandle that only writes wrapped text?

My workaround so far is to write to the auxiliary file between `\iffalse`...`\fi`, but I know that's not what the aux file is for.  I don't feel like writing this metadata to another file.  Yes, I'm being stubborn, but TeX means you can usually get anything you want if you work hard enough.  Can I do this?

**Edit:** Here's something else that doesn't work.  Open another filehandle with the same filename.

```
\newwrite\logfilenowrap
\immediate\openout\logfilenowrap=\jobname.log
```

Then `\immediate\write\logfilenowrap{long text}` will not wrap lines.  But it lops off everything that was in the logfile before this point (of course it does.  Opening a file handle usually puts the pointer at the front).

**Edit 2:** Thanks for all the replies.  Consensus is that this is "probably" not possible.  I'll go the route of writing metadata to a separate text file.

Comment: I’m not sure, but maybe something in [Will’s answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3595/how-can-i-word-wrap-latex-warning-error-output/3646#3646) to the orthogonally named question [“How can I word-wrap LaTeX warning/error output?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3595/how-can-i-word-wrap-latex-warning-error-output/3646#3646) helps.

Comment: I wish, but that seems to be about inserting extra newlines.  I want to avoid the ones which are there.

Comment: As others have said, I don't think this is possible. I'd probably do the explicit hard wrapping ( [package](http://github.com/wspr/hardwrap) to appear shortly) and insert a special char to indicate where to soft-wrap in post-processing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am pretty sure the wrapping behaviour is hardwired in TeX itself. Why can't you simply write to a separate file instead?

```
\newwrite\mylog
\immediate\openout\mylog=\jobname.mylog
```

Comment: Sure, I can.  I just wanted to cut down on the amount of files lying around.  If I decide to create a separate file for metadata, I start thinking about RDF which is a favorite pet project/rat hole of mine.  So I wanted to keep things simple.

Answer (score 19):

Output file line wrapping is controlled by the `max_print_line` setting in texmf.cnf (for TeX Live, miktex may have another system that I do not know).

The default setting is:

```
max_print_line = 79
```

Comment: Miktex knows max_print_line too. It can be set temporarly with the option --max-print-line=150  or in the .ini files by calling e.g. initexmf --edit-config-file pdflatex and then adding max_print_line=150. The second must be done for each compiler which should use this setting.

Comment: No `texmf.cnf` file on my machine has this setting in it.  But I assume from your answer that whatever it is has to be a positive number.  In other words, it can't be shut off.

Comment: Correct. But you can give it is very high value :)

Comment: Excellent answer - it's saved me hours of pain with a similar problem as the OP's. Just for the record on my MacPorts installation of texlive, I did `kpsewhich texmf.cnf` to locate the configuration file, upped max_print_line to 1000 and then ran `texconfig init` to put the new setting into effect.

Comment: I don't even think `texconfig init` is necessary.  in my case, just adding the max-print-line in `/usr/local/texlive/yyyy/texmf.cnf` was sufficient.

Comment: In most shells you can even just add it to your TeX invocation on a one-off basis: `max_print_line=10000 tex hello.tex` (or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ max_print_line=14000 pdflatex hello.tex
```

The `14000` is just a big number.

(This is in @shreevatsaR's comment, but it's easier to read if it is surfaced as an answer.)

Answer (score 0):

For the case of `pdflatex` provided by `MiKTeX`, you can set `max_print_line` directly to some larger number - 191 here:

```
[IO.File]::WriteAllLines("$Env:AppData\MiKTeX\miktex\config\pdftex.ini", "max_print_line=191")
```

which creates `pdftex.ini` with a file encoding that allows it to be read by MiKTeX's `pdflatex`, ie UTF-8 with no BOM.