# Avoid linebreaks in LaTeX console / log output (or increase columns in terminal)

Tags: compiling, automation, logging, terminal-output

Is it possible to tell the LaTeX command not to use line breaks in its console / log output?

This would make it easier to automate the processing of the log file, e.g. extracting the names of missing graphics files like in this output

```
! LaTeX Error: File `figures/triggers/muontriggers/notmu18_medium_mu10_loose/2d
map_abs_eta_phi.pdf' not found.
```

which are otherwise cut into pieces and unnecessarily difficult to `grep` etc.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4047/write-to-log-without-wrapping. One of the answers there might help.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can modify the `texmf.cnf` variables `error_line` and `max_print_line`, adding to the "local" `texmf.cnf` file, whose location depends on the distribution you're using; for TeX Live it is

```
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf.cnf
```

and the lines to be added are

```
max_print_line=1000
error_line=254
half_error_line=238
```

The first number is actually arbitrary, but 1000 seems to be sufficient. The `error_line` variable must be less than 255 and the maximum value of `half_error_line` is less than `error_line`-15

For experimenting you can also set the variables in the environment; assuming a Bash shell,

```
export max_print_line=1000
export error_line=254
export half_error_line=238
```

You can find the location of the various `texmf.cnf` files, in the order they're looked at, by running

```
kpsewhich -a texmf.cnf
```

from the command line. On my system I get

```
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf.cnf
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf
```

The “year part” in the path can and will vary according to the currently installed version of TeX Live.

Comment: `export max_print_line=1000` works perfect for me. Thanks.

Comment: For me too, but I had to include it to Makefile or bashrc. The `texmf.cnf` file seems to be ignored.

Comment: This may be useful: `export max_print_line=$(expr $(tput cols) - 1)` (terminal-width - 1). Of course, the `expr` can be removed for full-width.

Comment: Is there a way of changing this through the setting menu in TeXStudio? Is there a way to locate the texmf.cnf file? It is not where you suggest it should be. (Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: @Kvothe You can do `kpsewhich -a texmf.cnf` in order to list all the `texmf.cnf` files in the order they're read in. Modify the first one to add the settings.

Answer (score 19):

In MiKTeX you can use the option `--max-print-line=140` to get longer log lines. This will also affect the output in the command line window but only if have enlarged it before.

Comment: I couldn't find the text.mf file on Windows. I made it to work from Texworks. Just modified the `max_print_line parameter` from "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\config\texmfapp.ini" file.

Comment: _texmfapp.ini_ could be also located in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\config\texmfapp.ini` (if MiKTeX is installed in _user mode_)