# Undefined control sequence error

Tags: equations, document-classes

it might be a stupid question but I cannot see where the mistake is in this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\leftmargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{21cm}
\renewcommand{\hoffset}{1cm}
\renewcommand{\voffset}{1cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
H_{0}:\rho_{1}<0\text{ and }\rho_{2}>0
\end{equation}
$vs$
\begin{equation}
H_{A}:\rho _{1}\geqslant 0\text{and/or}\rho _{2}\leqslant 0.  \label{12}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I got an error message saying "Undefined control sequence". Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the rest of the message? It should indicate which command it doesn't recognise. (See the image at the top [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/309034) which shows an undefined control sequence error followed by the debugging information.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The undefined control sequence is `\text`, which is defined by package `amstext`, which is automatically loaded by `amsmath`. Thus, the minimal

```
\usepackage{amstext}
```

or the more powerful

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

fixes the issue.