# How to set environment variables for TeX in Latexmk?

Tags: linux, latexmk, environment-variables

By setting `max_print_line=1000` in `texmf.cnf` or the environment, [the logfile becomes more readable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52988/avoid-linebreaks-in-latex-console-log-output).

How should we set the environment in `.latexmk`?

I want to set the variable per project. Not global.

Comment: Any special reason why you want to set it in `.latexmk` and not simply in `texmf.cnf`?

Comment: You could make an alias for `alias mylatexmk='export max_print_line=1000; latexmk` (if you are not using bash, the commands need to be adjusted accordingly)

Comment: @samcarter that is not so clean. It would apply for all projects then. Besides that I think it belongs to the "makefile". One could make a `run.sh` but there is latexmk already which should manage this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just put

```
$ENV{max_print_line} = $log_wrap = 1000;
```

in the project's `.latexmkrc` file.  The Perl variable `$ENV{max_print_line}` is equivalent to the corresponding environment variable for the OS, and it is passed to all the programs that `latexmk` invokes.  The corresponding internal variable for `latexmk` is `$log_wrap`, and is used in its analysis of log files.

(Notes to myself as `latexmk` maintainer: `Latexmk` should be changed so that it uses `$ENV{max_print_line}` instead of `$log_wrap` whenever it is found that the environment variable is set.  Also `$log_wrap` should be documented although it currently isn't.)