# texlive: Personal "texmf.cnf"

Tags: texmf.cnf

I was wondering what is the official way to add personal configurations to `texmf.cnf`.

I specifically want to add my own settings for this reason:
[Avoid linebreaks in LaTeX console / log output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52988/avoid-linebreaks-in-latex-console-log-output)

But the answer there tells you to modify `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf.cnf`, which is *not right.*  Each time you install a new version of texlive, each time you reinstall texlive, each time you acquire a new machine, each time you wipe out your system disk, you would have to modify `texmf.cnf`.

All personal configurations should reside under the user's home directory.

I've heard of the environmental variable TEXMFCNF and searched the net for how to use it, but I haven't found what exactly it does and how to use it to solve the particular problem I have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `TEXMFCNF` environment variable tells TeX (or rather, the `kpathsea` library used by TeX in typical distributions) where to look for the `texmf.cnf` file. (You can type `kpsewhich texmf.cnf` to see the location of the `texmf.cnf` file that will get picked up.)

For me, by default, `kpsewhich texmf.cnf` shows `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf.cnf`. But if I set `TEXMFCNF` to something else:

```
% export TEXMFCNF='/tmp'
% kpsewhich texmf.cnf   
warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: /tmp.
```

However, if I instead `export TEXMFCNF='/tmp:'` then kpathsea searches in `/tmp` first, and then the default system directories (like `/usr/local/texlive/2017/` or whatever).

The documentation for all this is in the `kpathsea` manual, sections [Path searching > Path sources > Config files](https://tug.org/texinfohtml/kpathsea.html#Config-files), and [Path searching > Path expansion > Default expansion](https://tug.org/texinfohtml/kpathsea.html#Default-expansion) (for the stuff about the colon).

---

So the answer to your question, of how to maintain a local `texmf.cnf` file inside your user's home directory, is:

1. Create a file called `texmf.cnf`, in some place inside your home directory, say in `~/tex_config_dir`. Put whatever config changes you'd like, into this file.
2. Somewhere in your shell config (`.bashrc` or `.zshrc` or whatever you use), set the environment variable `TEXMFCNF` to point to that directory, ending with a colon. For example:

   ```
   export TEXMFCNF='~/tex_config_dir:'
   ```
3. In any new shell (for example, after restarting your terminal), type `echo $TEXMFCNF` to confirm that it's set correctly, and `kpsewhich texmf.cnf` to confirm that your config file is the one getting picked up. Enjoy.

Comment: One thing that's not clear to me is how to *merge* your settings with the ones which are already in `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf.cnf`.  Perhaps you have to copy what's in the original `texmf.cnf` and add your stuff to it?

Comment: @Ryo No you just have to add the changes you want. See the [documentation section](https://tug.org/texinfohtml/kpathsea.html#Config-files) linked above: “Kpathsea reads *all* `texmf.cnf` files in the search path, not just the first one found; definitions in earlier files override those in later files.”

Comment: Thanks! (I should've read the documentation before posting the comment.)  So, `texmf.cnf` is special in this sense. I think LaTeX normally reads the version of the file it first finds and stops the search there.

Answer (score 2):

`TEXMFCNF` is an environment variable saying where to find `texmf.cnf`. But there are some quirks:

- `TEXMFCNF` does not point to `texmf.cnf` itself, but the dir containing it.
- Its value can have a `:` in the end, which means *keep searching if not found here*.

An example `TEXMFCNF` setting (on unix-like system) is:

```
export TEXMFCNF=$HOME/.texlive:
```

This will search for `$HOME/.texlive/texmf.cnf` (then search other places if not found there).

I suggest using `kpsewhich --all texmf.cnf` to test if your settings are successful.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot locations where kpathsea will look for `texmf.cnf` and it will use all it can find: values in earlier texmf.cnf overrides the values from later texmf.cnf.

The main `texmf.cnf` is in `texlive/2017/texmf-dist/web2c`. This should never be changed.

The one in `texlive/2017` can be used for personal changes (open it to see the comments). But if you don't trust the location you can use the `web2c` folder of other texmf trees, e.g. texmf-local. A list of all possible location can be shown with `kpsewhich -show-path=cnf`.

You can also set the variable TEXMFCNF to a specific folder with the texmf.cnf but normally I don't think that it is needed.

Comment: Thanks that is informative. But if I don't set `TEXMFCNF`, then *all* the paths shown by `kpsewhich -show-path=cnf` start with `/usr`, i.e. none is in the user's home directory which is the main thing the OP asks for. So I think your answer is missing the main part of the question (maybe setting texmfhome)?

Comment: From the [Kpathsea manual](https://tug.org/texinfohtml/kpathsea.html), section [5 Path searching](https://tug.org/texinfohtml/kpathsea.html#Path-searching) > [5.2 Path sources](https://tug.org/texinfohtml/kpathsea.html#Path-sources) > [5.2.1 Config files](https://tug.org/texinfohtml/kpathsea.html#Config-files): “definitions in **earlier** files override those in **later** files”.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: On the other hand, if the problem is simply to avoid that a custom setting is overwritten by later updates, then one of the locations in the compile-time defaults of `TEXMFCNF`, namely, `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/web2c`, can be of interest.  Of course, a `texmf.cnf` file placed there would affect all users of a given machine, and placing it there would require appropriate access priviledges.

Comment: @GuM Yes that's exactly the problem; the expectation is that the user's config can be set in the user's directory. E.g. for my Emacs or Vim config I edit `~/.emacs` or `~/.vimrc`, not `/usr/...`. So: (1) the user does not need admin privileges, (2) the user's setting won't affect other users, (3) the user's preferences persist across system or distribution reinstalls (4) the user can sync their config files to other computers, etc. I *think* this answer says there exists a way of achieving this (having config inside `~` as asked) without setting TEXMFCNF, but it's not clear what that way is.

Comment: @GuM I mixed up earlier and later (but I guess you got the meaning anyway).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: I'm not sure about texmfhome (I removed the reference), it is not in my cnf-search path. But I'm on windows and it could be different in other systems.

Comment: Oh good point, I somehow forgot about Windows (maybe some cues in the question). I guess the conventions and expectations may be different on Windows.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: As far as I can understand, there’s no way of having (active)`texmf.cnf` files inside `~` *except* by setting `TEXMFCNF` in the environment: indeed, it is impossible to set the search path for `texmf.cnf` files within a `texmf.cnf` file, so the next source that is looked up after the environment is the compile-time path (see section [5.2 Path sources](https://tug.org/texinfohtml/kpathsea.html#Path-sources); and the compile-time path gets at most to `$SELFAUTOGRANDPARENT/texmf-local/web2c`, that expands to `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/web2c`, in the machine-wide custom tree.