# Instructing TeX to use an editor of my choice

Tags: errors, texlive, tex-core, editors

When I run TeX on a file containing an error (e.g. an undefined control sequence), I receive this message

```
Type <return> to proceed, S to scroll future error messages,
R to run without stopping, Q to run quietly,
I to insert something, E to edit your file,
1 or ... or 9 to ignore the next 1 to 9 tokens of input,
H for help, X to quit.
?
```

If I type "E" to edit my file, I then receive

```
...
I cannot find emacs in the PATH.
```

Is it possible to change the editor from emacs to one that is installed on my system?

If so, what would the procedure be?

(My TeX distribution is TeX Live 2021, if that is relevant.)

Comment: very few people use `e` these days, it is far more common to stay within the editor and run tex from within the editor rather than fire up a new editor when you get an error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I learned that it's possible to do both, since my editor has a built-in terminal and also a command-line switch to reuse the running instance if invoked from elsewhere

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to set the `TEXEDIT` environment variable in your `texmf.cnf` file.  To find this file you can run `kpsewhich texmf.cnf` which, on Linux, should be `/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf.cnf` if you used the default installation directory.

The default for `TEXEDIT` is:

```tex
%TEXEDIT = vi +%d '%s'                    % default for Unix
%TEXEDIT = texworks --position=+%d "%s"   % default for Windows
```

In the `TEXEDIT` line, the `'%s'` is the file name wrapped around quotes to preserve spaces, and `%d` is the line number.  If your editor doesn't open at a specific line number, you can omit `%d`.

Since you didn't say which editor you are using, here are a few options (found on the internet; most of them untested), in alphabetic order:

```c
TEXEDIT = atom "%s":+%d
TEXEDIT = emacs +%d "%s"
TEXEDIT = nano +%d "%s"
TEXEDIT = start notepad++ "%s" -n%d
TEXEDIT = subl "%s":+%d
TEXEDIT = texstudio --line "+%d" "%s"
TEXEDIT = texworks --position=+%d "%s"
TEXEDIT = vi +%d "%s"
TEXEDIT = vim +%d "%s"
```

Comment: I was able to get it working (I am on Windows).  Is there another directory for the texmf.cnf file so as to be year-independent?  Or would I need to redo this every time I upgrade the distribution?

Comment: @user244733 On Linux, I'd do [what's described here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410610/134574), so there should be a similar procedure on Windows. i.e.: create a common `texmf.cnf` and create an environment variable called `TEXMFCNF` that points to the folder that contains that file.

Comment: I think I got it to work.  Using a colon at the end of the path in the definition of `TEXMFCNF` as described in the post gave me the warning `kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: $TEXMFCNF` when I typed `kpsewhich -all texmf.cnf`.  If I used a semicolon instead of a colon, there is no warning and it yields the paths to my personal `texmf.cnf` and the distribution `texmf.cnf` files.  Maybe it is a Windows thing

Comment: @user244733 yes web2c paths use `;` on windows to allow `:` to be used for drive letters.

Comment: One can also set `TEXEDIT` in the environment, which would override the value in `texmf.cnf`