# Better latex output, instead of being wrapped on Terminal?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, luatex, mactex, terminal-output

Latex output is being wrapped, even if there is space on Terminal:

[image]

While if I list the files `ls` command output seems normal (as expected):

[image]

I checked [Avoid linebreaks in LaTeX console / log output (or increase columns in terminal)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52988/avoid-linebreaks-in-latex-console-log-output-or-increase-columns-in-terminal) and tried `export max_print_line=1000` but that gives:

[image]

Although `export max_print_line=120` is better then nothing.

Why is so? How do I get LaTex to use all space available nicely? By nicely I mean, can it break line after close of parentheses?

Sorry 1: If this is not a LaTex issue (perhaps I should ask on stackoverflow or askdifferent?).

Sorry 2 : Because I changed question a bit, I think is not a duplicate now.

Comment: You can try increasing the number of columns, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173753/how-can-i-set-the-default-width-height-and-position-of-my-mac-terminal-app.

Comment: I tried, doesn'
t help here.

Comment: One could argue of course that `ls` is wrong ... the 80-column width is _very_ well establish

Comment: I'll appreciate a more verbose comment if you don't mind please.