# WinEdt console wrapping

Tags: winedt

The output of LaTeX's console/terminal window is wrapped. I do not know if this has to do with LaTeX or WinEdt. It is very annoying to have a line wrapped when there is plenty of space for it not to be. How do I stop the console output from wrapping when using WinEdt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `max_print_line=XXX` to the `texmf-defaults.ini` where XXX is the max line size.

Comment: For MiKTeX installation: instead of texmf-defaults.ini you could try to find _texmfapp.ini_ file. It could be located in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\config\texmfapp.ini` (if MiKTeX is installed in _per-user mode_; or in `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\config\texmfapp.ini` in _all users (system-wide) mode_).

Answer (score 2):

There are three possible sources of wrapping

1. The editor display. WinEdt (as installed) uses the full width of the window to display the log, but that is not necessarily true of other editors. This may of course be altered in the GUI, but I doubt this is the problem here.
2. The source of messages. It's common to include hard wrapping in the text of LaTeX messages using `\MessageBreak`. There is not so much you can do about this, although LaTeX3 messages are 'auto-wrapped' and so should not be as bad.
3. Wrapping by the binaries. This is the most likely source of the wrapping described in the question. The wrap line length can be altered as described in [Write to log without wrapping](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4047/write-to-log-without-wrapping): the standard line length is 80 characters.