# draw a many edge from a node- Tree - tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, trees

i want to draw the tree in the following picture :

[image]

i have write :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{color}

 \definecolor{red}{rgb}{1,0,0} 
 \begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance=50mm]
  \tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling distance=30mm]
   \node(a) {\textcolor{red}{2}|2}
        child {node(b) {\textcolor{red}{2}|4}
        child {node(f) {\textcolor{red}{2}|4}}
            child {node(g)[rectangle, draw] {
            \scalebox{0.6}{% size of the array
                 \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
                            \textcolor{red}{2}|4 & \textcolor{red}{2}|4 & \textcolor{red}{2}|4 & \textcolor{red}{2}|4 & \textcolor{red}{2}|4 & \textcolor{red}{2}|4
                        \end{tabular}
                        }
            }}
            child {node(d) {\textcolor{red}{5} | 2}}
            }
   child {node(c)[rectangle, draw] {
\scalebox{0.8}{% size of the array
 \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
            \textcolor{red}{2}|4 & \textcolor{red}{2}|4 & \textcolor{red}{2}|4 & \textcolor{red}{2}|4 & \textcolor{red}{2}|4 & \textcolor{red}{2}|4
        \end{tabular}
        }
}}
            child {node(e) {\textcolor{red}{7} | 2}
            child {node(f) {\textcolor{red}{2}|4}}
            child {node(g)[rectangle, draw] {
            \scalebox{0.6}{%
                 \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
                            \textcolor{red}{2}|4 & \textcolor{red}{2}|4 & \textcolor{red}{2}|4 & \textcolor{red}{2}|4 & \textcolor{red}{2}|4 & \textcolor{red}{2}|4
                        \end{tabular}
                        }
              }}
              child {node(d) {\textcolor{red}{5} | 3}}
               }
  ;

  \draw[dashed] (a) -- (b);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get this result :

[image]

How can i proceed to draw the many egde form the array child of the parent to the other child , thank u in advance

Comment: Have you thought of using the `rectangle split` node shape? Although the [PGF manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) only shows the anchors of a vertically split node, there are probably also proper anchors for a horizontally split node (`.text south`, `.two south`, `.three south`, …?).

Comment: You have repeated node names: `d`, `f`, `g`

Comment: If you were thinking about the red dashed lines parallel to the actual edges the `/pgf/decoration/raise` option may come in handy.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel i have put for example \draw[decorate,decoration={raise=6pt,amplitude=10pt}, thick] (a)--(b); 
but it does not work

Comment: @WassimSboui For once, you have at least to specify a decoration (the manual uses `crosses`). On the other side `decoration={lineto,raise=6pt}` does not work either, so more effort will be needed to make that work. The next best thing would be a custom `to path`, I guess.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Summary

- Fixed the node names. For easier reference, I named the node from top to bottom, left to right with `a,b,...`.
- As suggested by  **Qrrbrbirlbel**, I used the `rectangle split` node shape available in the library `shapes.multipart` instead of the `tabular` environment.
- Instead of defining a new `to path` I used the `brace` decoration from the `decorations.pathreplacing` library instead and set `amplitude=0pt`. Hacky, but it works.
- I removed `\scalebox` and replaced this with `scale=0.8`.
- **Update** <strike>I encolsed each `|` with `$...$`.</strike> As mentioned by Qrrbrbirbel in comment, to draw the pipes: `|`, use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in your preamble: [How to insert pipe symbol in (La)TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/how-to-insert-pipe-symbol-in-latex). For good measure, write also `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.
- Instead of defining the coordinates in terms of the default ones in the `rectangle split` node shape, I defined them relative to only two coordinates of the node.
- I replaced `\tikzstyle`, which is deprecated, with `\tikzset`.
- There is no need to define `red` as color since this is already predefined. Also, there is no need to load the `color` package since `tikz` uses `xcolor` internally.

## Updated Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
%\documentclass[10pt]{article}
%\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,calc,decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzset{
    my shape 1/.style={circle, draw},
    my shape 2/.style={
        rectangle split, 
        rectangle split parts=#1, 
        draw, 
        anchor = center, 
        rectangle split horizontal},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \tikzset{level 1/.style={sibling distance=50mm},
             level 2/.style={sibling distance=30mm}}
    \node (a) [my shape 1] {\textcolor{red}{2}|2}
    child {node(b) [my shape 1] {\textcolor{red}{2}|4}
        child {node(e) [my shape 1] {\textcolor{red}{2}|4}}
        child {node(f)[my shape 2=6,scale=0.8] {
                \textcolor{red}{2}|4 \nodepart{two} \textcolor{red}{2}|4 \nodepart{three} \textcolor{red}{2}|4 \nodepart{four} \textcolor{red}{2}|4 \nodepart{five} \textcolor{red}{2}|4 \nodepart{six} \textcolor{red}{2}|4
            }}
        child {node(g) [my shape 1] {\textcolor{red}{5}|2}}
        }
    child {node(c)[my shape 2=6,scale=0.8] {
            \textcolor{red}{2}|4 \nodepart{two} \textcolor{red}{2}|4 \nodepart{three} \textcolor{red}{2}|4 \nodepart{four} \textcolor{red}{2}|4 \nodepart{five} \textcolor{red}{2}|4 \nodepart{six} \textcolor{red}{2}|4
            }}
    child {node(d) [my shape 1] {\textcolor{red}{7}|2}
        child {node(h) [my shape 1] {\textcolor{red}{2}|4}}
        child {node(i)[my shape 2=6,scale=0.8] {
                \textcolor{red}{2}|4 \nodepart{two} \textcolor{red}{2}|4 \nodepart{three} \textcolor{red}{2}|4 \nodepart{four} \textcolor{red}{2}|4 \nodepart{five} \textcolor{red}{2}|4 \nodepart{six} \textcolor{red}{2}|4
                    }}
        child {node(j) [my shape 1] {\textcolor{red}{5}$|$3}}
                };

    \foreach \xleft/\leftpos in {1/0.416,3/0.2083,5/.375,7/.542,9/.7083,11/.875} {
        \coordinate (c\xleft) at ($(c.south west)!\leftpos!(c.south east)$);
        \coordinate (f\xleft) at ($(f.north west)!\leftpos!(f.north east)$);}

    \foreach \x/\arrowcol in {1/blue,3/green,5/red,7/yellow,9/orange,11/purple}
        \draw [->,\arrowcol] (c\x)  .. controls ++(-90:0.5) and ++(0:0.5) .. ($(c\x)!.5!(f\x)$)
            ($(c\x)!.5!(f\x)$) .. controls ++(180:0.5) and ++(90:0.5) .. (f\x);

    \foreach \xright/\rightpos in {2/.125,4/.2917,6/.4583,8/.625,10/.7917,12/.9583} {
        \coordinate (c\xright) at ($(c.south west)!\rightpos!(c.south east)$);
        \coordinate (i\xright) at ($(i.north west)!\rightpos!(i.north east)$);}

    \foreach \x/\arrowcol in {2/blue,4/green,6/red,8/yellow,10/orange,12/purple}
        \draw [->,\arrowcol,dashed] (c\x)  .. controls ++(-90:0.5) and ++(0:0.5) .. ($(c\x)!.5!(i\x)$)
            ($(c\x)!.5!(i\x)$) .. controls ++(180:0.5) and ++(90:0.5) .. (i\x);

    \draw [postaction={draw,decorate,decoration={brace,raise=-3pt,amplitude=0pt},dashed,red}] (a) -- (b);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (a*) at (c9);
\coordinate (b*) at ([yshift=-0.2cm]a*);
\draw (a*) -- (b*);
\draw ([xshift=-0.3cm]b*) -- ([xshift=0.3cm]b*);
\foreach \x in {-0.8,-0.4,0,.4,0.8}
\draw ([xshift=\x em]b*) -- +(-0.1,-0.2);
\end{document}
```

## Updated Output

[image]

Comment: About that `|`: [How to insert pipe symbol in (La)TeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1774)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks for that! I have updated the answer. `:-)`

Comment: Those coordinate declarations beg for `\foreach` ;)

Comment: @hpesoj626 Thank u for ur work , but how about the Chassis ground ? http://www.google.fr/imgres?um=1&hl=fr&tbo=d&biw=1276&bih=662&tbm=isch&tbnid=qaLTgfLyNs-_HM:&imgrefurl=http://www.epsic.ch/cours/electronique/techn99/elniq/ELNMODL.html&docid=ZUnV3gmUcvzK_M&imgurl=http://www.epsic.ch/cours/electronique/techn99/elniq/elnmodl6.gif&w=346&h=178&ei=Cd_7UMyON4KIhQf6zIB4&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=364&sig=108752475345136813083&page=2&tbnh=121&tbnw=238&start=26&ndsp=33&ved=1t:429,r:34,s:0,i:186&tx=162&ty=56

Comment: @WassimSboui I didn't know that it was part of your question. I don't know if there is a pre-defined shape like that. I looked at [`circuitikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz) but this is the ground that I saw http://www.epsic.ch/cours/electronique/techn99/elniq/elnmodl6.gif. But the figure are just composed of segments so it will not be hard to create. See my edit.

Comment: @WassimSboui I added your request but I suggest that you limit your questions to one per post in the future. This helps readers searching for questions find specific solutions. I drew the ground chassis manually but perhaps you can ask as a separate question how one can create such a circuit symbol so that it can be used repeatedly throughout your figure by just invoking its name. I might not be able to help since that is beyond me at this point. But other users of the site might be able to help. `:-)`