# How to write the | (pipe) character without interpreting it?

Tags: symbols, unicode

I'm writing a LaTeX document in which I have to write many "|" characters which are not part of a mathematical formula.

Simply writing `test | test` gives me something like (after compilation) : `test - test` and I don't want the line to become horizontal.

What I've tried so far:

- `test \| test` (this does not even work at compilation)
- `\usepackage{amsmath}`

  `test $$ \mid $$ test` (this quite works but implies line breaks... Whatsmore I don't need to write mathematical formulas)
- `test \char124 test` (this also gives me `test - test` !!)

I've well written `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` at the beginning of my document.

What I use for compilation:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)

I'm surprised that I could not found any topic nor tutorial that tells how to write pipes correctly... Does someone have an idea about how to proceed? Maybe I'm doing something bad? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You might want to try `\textbar`

Comment: Or you could use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. T1 has a glyph for |.

Comment: See also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/how-to-insert-pipe-symbol-in-latex/41475#41475

Comment: Thank you for your interesting replies. jonalv, I'm sorry (and surprised) for not having found this helpful topic earlier !