# Formatting data dictionaries in LaTeX

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I would like to write out some *data dictionaries* for a program design document in LaTeX, and I am looking for an efficient way to do this.

I want to write snippets that look like:

```
Name      = FirstName + (Initial) + LastName
FirstName = 1{Character}32
Initial   = Character
LastName  = 1{Character}
Character = [ A-Z | a-z | 0-9 | ' | - ]
```

It's important that these are lined up at the `=` signs - they look ugly without it.

I could write this as the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \text{Name}      &= \text{FirstName + (Initial) + LastName} \\
    \text{FirstName} &= \text{1\{Character\}32} \\
    \text{Initial}   &= \text{Character} \\
    \text{LastName}  &= \text{1\{Character\}} \\
    \text{Character} &= \text{[ A -- Z $|$ a -- z $|$ 0 -- 9 $|$ ' $|$ -- ]} \\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

but this feels pretty clunky with all of the `\text{}` commands. Is there a simpler method?

Comment: Would a `verbatim` environment do? Try placing that first snippet you show between `\begin{verbatim}` and `\end{verbatim}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Actually, that looks perfect! Why didn't I think of that? (It also solves my un-asked problem of writing out those vertical bars; two birds, one stone.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to leave alignment to LaTeX rather than spacing manually in `verbatim`, you can do something like this with `tabular` (or `longtable` if the dictionary is long):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l@{~=~}l}
Name & FirstName + (Initial) + LastName\\
FirstName & 1\{Character\}32\\
Initial & Character\\
LastName & 1\{Character\}\\
Character & [ A-Z | a-z | 0-9 | ' | - ]\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The point of including non-breaking spaces in the table specification is to keep the equals signs and the text apart. Tables are also easier to customise if you want to change the layout.

If you want to use a typewriter font, simply put a `\ttfamily` in front of the start of `tabular` and enclose them in braces.

Comment: Add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to fix the printing of the pipe character, which display as em dashes with your code. (Cf. [How to insert pipe symbol in (La)TeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1775))

Comment: @TorbjørnT. That's right. Interestingly, adding `\ttfamily` fixes this issue as well, but I don't see why.

Comment: I like this a lot. I'm now using this as 

`\newenvironment{ddict}
 {\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{l@{~=~}l}}
 {\end{tabular}\end{center}}`

Answer (score 3):

When you have the dictionaries already lined up as in your example, an easy way is to use a `verbatim` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
Name      = FirstName + (Initial) + LastName
FirstName = 1{Character}32
Initial   = Character
LastName  = 1{Character}
Character = [ A-Z | a-z | 0-9 | ' | - ]
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```