# How to print a vertical bar if it is \active?

Tags: catcodes, active-characters

I'm trying to print a vertical bar symbol, but it's `\active` in the `ltxdoc` document style (this code doesn't compile):

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\begin{document}
This is a vertical bar: |\||
\end{document}
```

I want the bar to be inside `|...|` formatting, which essentially is `\texttt{...}` in this document style. What would be a solution?

Comment: Actually https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41475/250119 works although is clumsy.

Comment: It works, but it renders the bar in a different font. It's similar to `$\vert$`. Also clumsy, as you said :(

Comment: Okay then, easiest way to understand is `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \texttt{ab\textbar cd}`. Anything else (that I can think of) involves a nontrivial amount of TeX programming/understanding.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Please, make it an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy-to-understand solution is

```
%! TEX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  % pdflatex only!! in other engine omit this line or specify encoding TU
% in pdflatex without this line the vertical bar would not be in typewriter font

\begin{document}

\texttt{ab\textbar cd}

\end{document}
```

You will not be able to use `|ab\textbar cd|` here because it's verbatim and will print `\textbar`  verbatim (nevertheless `|ab\textbar cd|` can be used inside another command's argument if it's a "real argument" but I don't recommend relying on this inconsistent behavior, would be confusing)

---

For the sake of overcomplicating things, this is a solution that allows you to escape the `|` by doubling it.

```
%! TEX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{ltxdoc}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter

\char_set_catcode_active:N \|

\AtBeginDocument{
    \char_set_active_eq:NN \| \__usersixdigits_vertical_bar_active_do:w
}

\char_set_catcode_other:N \|

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__usersixdigits_vertical_bar_active_do:w {
    \begingroup
    \let\do\@makeother
    \dospecials
    \__usersixdigits_grab_following_argument:w
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__usersixdigits_grab_following_argument:w #1 | {
    \endgroup  % reset the catcode of the following character (which might not be |)
    \texttt{#1}  % typeset the text collected so far
    % the following peek will tokenize the following argument, so it's important to |\endgroup| above
    \peek_meaning_remove:NT \__usersixdigits_vertical_bar_active_do:w  % we assume nothing other than the active | has this meaning
    {
        \texttt{|}  % assuming the current font has the | character in the correct slot (which means either T1/TU encoding or OT1 typewriter font)
        \__usersixdigits_vertical_bar_active_do:w
    }
}

\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}


some text |12||34|

vertical bar ||||

vertical bar |||| abc

ab|x||y|cd

ab|x||y|\{cd




\end{document}
```

Output is as you expect.

[image: output image]

Answer (score 2):

The bar is only a shorthand for `\verb`. So you can simply use `\verb` directly with as usual some delimiter which is not in the text:

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\begin{document}
This is a vertical bar: 
\verb+|+
\end{document}
```

Side remark: *inside |...| formatting* is the wrong concept. The shorthand is not about formatting (which can be changed), but allows verbatim typesetting. If you want to *format* in typewriter, use `\texttt` and `\textbar` (`\|` wouldn't work regardless if the bar is active or not, as `\|` is a math command). And if you want the bar to work like `\texttt` you will have to redefine it first.

Comment: This also works, except in command arguments where you can... apparently `\verb|12\textbar 3|` works.