# Teletype \textbackslash in alltt environment

Tags: verbatim

The `alltt` package provides a beefed up `verbatim` environment where `\` and `{}` are not treated literally. A literal backslash can be inserted with `\textbackslash`, however, it does not have the same teletype font as the rest of the verbatim text. I tried some variataions such as `\texttt{\textbackslash}` but these don't seem to help. Any ideas how to insert a backslash (or curly braces) in teletype font when using `alltt`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has nothing to do with alltt. You need T1-encoding. Without it \textbackslash is taken from the symbol font. Check the difference:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\ttfamily \textbackslash abc
\end{document}
```

Comment: Although using a different font encoding is an interesting approach, Leo's answer has the less "global impact" and I hence accepted it as solution.

Comment: `\textbackslash` is not the only symbol affected by the lack of chars in OT1. You will perhaps need similar definitions for braces (e.g. `\{` or `\}` `\textbraceleft`. `\textbraceright`) and greater/less symbol (`\textgreater`, `\textless`)). I advise you to drop OT1. The encoding is obsolete. Load T1 and perhaps even TS1 (e.g. with `\usepackage{textcomp}`).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I read a bit more on OT1 vs T1 (also stumbled over http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc/677#677). Is my understanding correct that T1 provides the necessary font symbols to render `\textbackslash` in all variants (such as `\ttfamily`, `\sffamily`, etc.) but the default font encoding OT1 does not?

Comment: @Matthias: Yes OT1 encoding has only 128 positions, so Knuth had to sacrifice consistency. E.g. braces and greater/less symbols are only in the typewriter fonts, the other fonts have eg. quotes at this positions. And on position 36 there is a dollar sign in upshape fonts and a pound sign in itshape as you can try out: `\char36 \itshape \char36`. I don't see any reason to accept such a mess when consistent encodings with 256 positions like T1 exist.

Answer (score 6):

In addition, you don't have to use `T1` font encoding. Default `OT1` is enough. In this case symbol `\` is not available in roman font family, but it does be available for tyrewriter family.

You can use

```
\symbol{`\\}
```

to get `\` at any time. If it is available in the font, a backslash should be output properly. You can define a command for it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alltt}
\newcommand\bslash{\symbol{`\\}}
\begin{document}

\begin{alltt}
\bslash{}^_^/
\end{alltt}

\end{document}
```

After all, it is a good manner to use `T1` encoding for most documents.

Answer (score 3):

while the suggestions to use a different encoding are good, this technique should
work anywhere to get a monospace symbol if it's in the font being used.

preface the input character by

```
\char`\
```

so that a backslash, open and close brace would be input as

```
\char`\\ \char`\{ \char`\}
```

this is built into TeX itself, not defined by any particular "flavor" such as LaTeX or ConTeXt.

EDIT: the `\char` command will reference whatever glyph is in the ascii/utf-8/(relevant font encoding) position corresponding to its argument.  so only if the backslash (or whatever) is *actually* in that location in the font will you get the desired shape.
my original answer was meant to refer specifically to `cmtt10` and other fonts encoded so that the input character exactly matches the glyph in that font location.

Comment: Well cmsy10 does contain the symbols but you can't access them with your commands: `\font\test=cmsy10 \test \char`\{ \char`\f` (the code is messed up due to the highlighting).

Comment: @Ulrike: see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code/864#864 for how to get Markdown to display that correctly.

Comment: @Caramdir Ah, thanks. So you can use either a backslash to escape a quote in the code: `a\`b` or double quotes outside: ``a`b ``

Comment: @Ulrike -- when i said "monospace symbol", i was thinking specifically of `cmtt10`; wouldn't expect it to work quite the same way with `cmsy10`, and actually, wouldn't want to mix `cmsy10` with `cmtt10` -- that was the complaint of the original poster. @Caramdir -- thanks for the pointer; my answer would have been more compact if i had known about the double quote.

Comment: @barbara: I know that you mean cmtt10. But imho your answer is misleading. It makes the impression as if TeX somehow knows that you want a backslash when you type ``\char`\\``. But this command (like the `\symbol`command of Leo) is simply another way to write `\char92` and it will give a backslash if and only if the font has a backslash at position 92 - which is the case amongst others for some OT1-encoded fonts and for all T1 encoded fonts. So I wanted to pointed out that it depends on the font if it works or not.

Comment: @Ulrike -- fair criticism.  i hope my edit has made the application of this technique less confusing.