# How to make a text { in alltt

Tags: verbatim

I am trying to type computer code in my document using the `alltt` environment. Some symbols, such as ' and {, do not appear in the document the way they do in the code. I solved the problem with ' by using the `upquote` package. But I still have a problem with { and }; these symbols are taller than the surrounding text in the `alltt` environment. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} %set margins
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{upquote}

\begin{document}

    \begin{alltt}
    for (i in 1:3){
        print(i^2)
        }
    \end{alltt}

\end{document}
```

doesn't do what I want (since the braces do not appear), and neither does using `\{` and `\}` in place of { and } (the braces are too tall). I think [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16833/teletype-textbackslash-in-alltt-environment) is something similar, but I do not understand the answers given there.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Why don't you use the `verbatim` environment?

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question to include compilable code.

Comment: Or use `listings` package.

Comment: From the `alltt` abstract: `This package defines the alltt environment, which is like the verbatim
environment except that \, {, and } have their usual meanings.
Thus, other commands and environments can appear within an alltt environment`.

Comment: @egreg that looks good! Do I not need to use alltt at all then? I thought for some reason that I needed it if I wanted to have my code in the typewriter font, but verbatim seems to use that font as well.

Comment: Thanks, that solves my problem; I'll just use verbatim instead. I have upvoted your comments!

Comment: @Flounderer in `alltt` you can use `\textbackslash` for \ and `\}` and `\{` for `}` and `{`, respectively.

Comment: If you want to get the correct braces in an `alltt` environment you should use `\{` `\}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` (which is a good idea anyway - a lot problems with wrong symbols are due to the restrictions of the default OT1-encoding).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `alltt` environment is a kind of "semiverbatim": it uses the typewriter font, but still `\`, `{` and `}` maintain their meaning, for being able to use commands (say for changing color, fonts or whatever).

For real verbatim, use the `verbatim` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{upquote}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
for (i in 1:3){
     print(i^2)
    }
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Limitation: you shouldn't "globally" indent it; all spaces at the beginning of lines are honored, so begin at the left margin and indent as much as you want inside the environment.

More features are provided by the `fancyvrb` package. Still many more are available with the very powerful `listings` package.