# Setting font family for the whole document

Tags: fonts, formatting

This looks like the basic question but it seems like the hardest thing to me.

I need to set the whole document's font style as follows :

> Font Family: *Times New Roman* or *GoudyOlSt BT*
>
> Font Size: *11pt*

I am doing something like below but have no effect at all :

```
\fontencoding{T1}
\fontfamily{garamond}
\fontseries{m}
\fontshape{it}
\fontsize{11}{14}
\selectfont
```

Also, that would be nice to see the available font-family styles if possible.

I would really appreciate if someone direct me to right way.

Comment: Times Roman fonts are supported by [`mathptmx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx), which you can specify together with an `11pt` document class option.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Fonts

You could use [TeX Gyre Termes](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/tgtermes/), [Times](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/times/) or [txfonts](http://ctan.org/pkg/txfonts). They are similar to Times New Roman (if you want to look at other fonts you should hunt for a similar serif font, see e.g. http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/seriffonts.html). Fonts are loaded and activated for a document by loading the package for the font via `\usepackage`. You probably want to use them with T1 encoding and to do this you should use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` (see [Why should I use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc/677#677)).

So, for TeX Gyre Termes you'd use:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
```

For Times:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
```

For txfonts:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{txfonts}
```

### Font size

To get 11pt font size simply add `11pt` as an option to `\documentclass`, so if you're using the article document class you'd use `\documentclass[11pt]{article}`.

### Example

The following is an example to illustrate one font. I use the package `lipsum` to get example text.

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: Outpus]

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. that works pretty well but I am having another type of problem right now. When  I set the font-size to 11pt, some of my figures aren't the place where they are supposed to be. maybe this is another question but I thought it might be a common porblem

Comment: @tugberk: This *is* another question. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to use the san serif font LMSS under the `lmodern` family. Just like the above post mentions, you have to use the right packages:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} % Font Family
```

It was essential (at least for me) to specify the following:

```
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{lmss}
```