# Why does my PDF render differently in Windows and Linux?

Tags: fonts, pdf, viewers, rendering

I'm not trying anything fancy just a plain vanilla

```
\title{Practical Node.js  }
```

However, in Linux the results look great (Document Viewer 3.2.1)

[image]

In windows it looks absolutely terrible (Adobe Reader 9)

[image]

Edit: I'm rendering PDFs online using http://www.scribtex.com

Edit2: Looks like it may be a problem with my reader on windows. Taking a different PDF compare

[image: Linux, smooth rendering]

to

[image: Windows, blurry font]

These are the fonts embedded in the document:

[image: screenshot of the fonts used in the document]

Comment: Using different readers is a heck of a variable. How does `acroread` render the PDF on Linux?

Comment: Beside the difference caused by the PDF reader you use, it seems to me that you use a bitmap font in Windows and a vector font in Linux...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You do not use the [Type 1 versions of Computer Modern](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/664/5763) on your Windows TeX installation. Install the cm-super fonts or better the Latin Modern fonts and use:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

Comment: I made an edit to the original question to reflect how the rendering is being done.  In both cases the same PDF is produced by scribtex.com.  I have added the packages and the rendering unfortunately still looks ordinary on Windows.  Funnily enough it looks fantastic in Windows/Chrome.

Comment: compare the embedded fonts in both pdf files. Are they identical?

Comment: There is only a single PDF file.  These are the fonts that are embedded http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12337149/code/embedded.png the list is the same on both operating systems

Comment: I suggest trying to compile it using a normal LaTeX install. Are you using PDFTeX? XeTeX? LuaTeX?

Comment: I have tried compiling with pdflatex and xelatex.  I have amended my question I think it might be a reader issue

Comment: I compiled a small example on scribtex.com. The resulting pdf uses type1 fonts (cm-super fonts), so the font type is not the problem. It must be a problem with the reader (or the settings in the reader).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Adobe Reader has some unfortunate defaults

http://tex.aanhet.net/rugtex/adoberead.html

Turning on font smoothing fixed things

Comment: You should not be using Adobe Reader to begin with on Windows machine. SumatraPDF viewer is far superior PDF viewer on Windows. If you like to stick to SumatraPDF libraries I would suggest that you try MuPDF on your Linux machine instead of other PDF viewers.

Comment: I would usually agree but came across some weird thing recently. Using Adobe Reader the generated letter looks nice, with its correct colors. Sumatra, however, shows completely  different colors which do not match the original ones by a magnitude. In this case I need to rely on Adobe.

Comment: Zoom in very far using Adobe Reader. Is the text vectorized or "bitmapped"?