# Kind of font used in one article

Tags: fonts

I would like to know what kind of font did the author of this [article](http://opus.bib.hochschule-bonn-rhein-sieg.de/opus-3.3/volltexte/2011/5/) use? I guess the article is of latex writing. How do I configure my preamble in order to use it. What kind of package needed to be included?

Comment: why don't you read the preferences of the pdf? Then you'll see that the default TeX fonts were used (CMR and LM)

Comment: How do I read "the preferences of the pdf"? Sorry, I'm pretty dumb about this.

Comment: I see, I've seen them in the properties, but they are mixed up, some use LM and some CMR.

Comment: yes, that are Computer Modern and Latin Modern. See my answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44318/why-does-my-pdf-render-differently-in-windows-and-linux/44319#44319 of what to do

Comment: After adding those packages(`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
` and `\usepackage{lmodern}`), and disable `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`, it still doesn't work. Is it because I'm on Linux? it makes no difference, I guess.

Comment: `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` should still be used. It has nothing to do with the font setting

Comment: They might be different font I think between your previous answer and the link I provided. In the properties, he used different one.

Comment: I'm particularly interested in getting the font of his sections and sub-sections, not the content.

Comment: The sections are in sans-serif.

Comment: How do I use it in my preamble? Could you give me one line of the code to include it..

Comment: The line might be `\let\familydefault\sfdefault` I hope. It should make **default** family to be **sf** (=sans-serif)

Comment: That `article` link didn't work for me.

Comment: I will close this question. The comments answered it, there's no real answer necessary as this question is too specific and localized. For follow-up questions please write a new question - please avoid discussion in comments, or visit us in the [chat].