# What are compact fonts for which I can easily set the font size to 11.75?

Tags: fonts, fontsize

As the title already says, I am looking for a nice font, which is also appropriate to write formulas in. It would be nice to be able to set the font size to 11.75 (I am a little bit short of space).

Comment: Any scalable font will do the job, for instance [`lmodern`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/lm/lm-info.pdf).  To use it with `pdflatex` place `\usepackage{lmodern}` in the preamble.

Comment: It's funny how this question is not vandalized by opinion based mafia.

Comment: @percusse -- according to mafia protocol, a truly powerful man never needs to express his opinions directly. He merely has to hint, and people know what they're supposed to do  :-)

Answer (score 12):

You can use any fonts available at http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/. How to use them at 11.75pts size ? The easiest way is to use Koma Script classes (`scrbook`, `scrreprt`, and `scrartcl`).

MWE :

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11.75pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}%random text
\usepackage{lmodern}%or any other font, see below my suggestions

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] 
\[ SE=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-2}\left[\sum^{n}_{i=1}(y_i-\overline{y})^2-\frac{\Big[\sum^{n}_{i=1}(x_i-\overline{x})(y_i-\overline{y})\Big]^2}{\sum^{n}_{i=1}(x_i-\overline{x})^2}\right]} \]
\end{document}
```

I am going to suggest you some fonts that are compatibles with math and that are compacts as needed. [cfr already made some good suggestions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285842/75487) but I am going to continue the list with Serif and Sans Serif fonts.

> Latin Modern (original `LaTeX` font) | Documentation : https://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/robertson/robertson.pdf

[image]

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

> CM Bright

[image]

```
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

> Concrete text with Euler math

[image]

```
\usepackage{ccfonts,eulervm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

> Iwona text and math

[image]

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[math]{iwona}
```

> Antykwa Półtawskiego

[image]

```
\usepackage{antpolt} %and
\usepackage[QX]{fontenc}
```

> New Century Schoolbook with Millennial math

[image]

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{millennial}
```

> Palatino text with pxfonts math

[image]

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pxfonts}
```

> URW Garamond text with Math Design math

[image]

```
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Answer (score 9):

[PMC1234 answered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285828/) the general question about the most straightforward way to use a non-standard font size. Latin Modern has already been suggested, but it might be nice to have a few options. Here's a selection of serifs, since I'm assuming that you are looking for a serif family for the main body text. I'm also assuming that you do not want a Times clone since this is such an obvious choice.

### *Latin Modern Roman* **cfr-lm**

[image: Latin Modern Roman]

### *Venturis ADF* **venturisadf**

[image: VenturisADF]

### *Berenis ADF Pro* **berenisadf**

[image: BerenisADFPro]

### *Antykwy Toruńskie Condensed* **antt**

[image: Antykwy Toruńskie Condensed]

### *Antykwy Polski* **polski**

[image: Antykwy Polski]

### *GFS Artemisia* **gfsartemisia**

[image: GFS Artemisia]

As others have said, Latin Modern is a sure choice if you need matching mathematical fonts. However, some of the others can work well in combination with suitable maths fonts and their manuals often include suggestions along these lines.

Code (switch to a KOMA class for easy access to 11.75pt):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
% uncomment one of the following
% \usepackage{venturis}
% \usepackage{berenis}
% \usepackage{cfr-lm}% or lmodern
% \usepackage[condensed]{anttor}
% \usepackage{polski}
% \usepackage{gfsartemisia}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for the large # of suggestions but primarily for **venturisadf** - which looks so nice from here that I think I'm going to have to use it somewhere :)

Comment: If you read the documentation, you can also do fancy stuff with it although it does not impose fancy things on you by default. (At least, it is not supposed to and I don't think it should.) It also has a number of shapes, weights and widths beyond the standard LaTeX fare. (That's true of Latin Modern as well, of course.)

Comment: Berenis looks highly readable!  What's a good, similarly well readable math font to go with it?

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of good suggestions here, but nothing much about your request for a *compact* font that will let you cram lots of text into little space.

If you use the fontspec package, there is a `fakestretch` parameter that will let you shrink the character shapes horizontally. People who regard fonts as works of art will be horrified by this butchery, but it probably won't look too bad if your scaling factor is not too extreme.

[This page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100577/fatter-computer-modern) shows some examples of the use of `fakestretch` with Latin Modern, but it will work with any Postscript font, presumably, including most of the ones mentioned in the other answers here.

Another idea: the larger sizes of Computer Modern are narrower, so you can save space by using CMR17 at 11.75pt size, rather than using CMR10 at 11.75pt. Again, typographic purists will be appalled, but you're going to have to break some rules if you really want to cram lots of text into your paper. Only you can say how much you're willing to sacrifice aesthetics to save space.

Comment: Er... The fonts listed are examples of fonts which are especially efficient in their use of space without any need to squeeze them artificially. Why abuse fonts when you could simply choose a font which is designed in a way which makes it compact? I listed compact fonts. You are explaining a way to compact fonts, but that is not at all the same. Why choose the aesthetically dubious alternative when there is a typographically clean option? Also the question you link probably needs *opentype* fonts. Some fonts here are available in that format, but most installed with TeX Live are type1.

Comment: In answer to your "why choose" questions .. it's not me that's doing the choosing. If the OP wants to use a "typographically dubious" approach to save space, that's up to him.

Comment: But the OP asked for compact fonts - not how to compact fonts.

Comment: Well, after they have been compacted, they are compact  :-)