# New Century Schoolbook with Millennial math not available in texlive-2016

Tags: fonts, ubuntu, font-encodings, texlive-2016

I have a fresh install of latex-live on ubuntu 16.04. I was trying to use New Century Schoolbook with millenial math (found it here http://tug.ctan.org/info/Free_Math_Font_Survey/survey.html#fig:Millen). I tried to use millennial as suggested here ([What are compact fonts for which I can easily set the font size to 11.75?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285815/what-are-compact-fonts-for-which-i-can-easily-set-the-font-size-to-11-75)). I get error saying millenial.sty not found. Is it not distributed officially anymore. If yes how do I use it from local fonts directory inside my project folder.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There has never been a `millennial` distribution in TeX Live. I could only find an “initial release” [click here to download](http://www.math.ucdenver.edu/~hartkes/computer/latex/Millennial-20110819.tar.bz2) You have to do manual installation, though. On the other hand, `fouriernc` seems to do the same, that is, providing a New Century Schoolbook compatible math font.

Comment: How can I use the downloaded `millennial` fonts. Can I specify in my tex file the relative folder from which to select the font. Pls suggest a guide if there is any. Btw I was using `fouriernc` for the time being. Thanks for suggesting it anyway.